# How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?

Tags: wireless, command-line, network-manager

Since the network manager is troubling me so much I want to replace it (possibly `wicd` or`NM` from **ppa:volanin**).

I do not know how to connect and disconnect to the network through the terminal without using network manager.

I would like a command-line way of managing the network.

Comment: If you are going to be messing with your system's network connection manager, I recommend that you do so while connected via wired ethernet, which is less likely to lose its connection, and easier to set up from the command line, should the need arise.

Comment: I use `wicd-curses`, which I find to be the easiest user interface by far. You need to use the <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow key `->`) to set configurations; everything else is obvious from the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 175):

This applies to 12.04+ since these are the ones I could test but could also be used in older versions. I have separated this guide into several parts, which consist of:

- **Part 1** Wireless Routers with no password or WEP Key
- **Part 2** Wireless Routers with WPA or WPA2 security Key

  - **Part 2.1** Connecting to a WPA Router with wpa_supplicant
  - **Part 2.2** Connecting to a WPA Router with Network Manager
- **Part 3** Easy Connection Via nmcli
- **Part 4** Disconnecting from a Wireless Router
- **Part 5** Deleting a Connection (Including Configuration File)
- **Part 6** Automatic connection when login in
- **Bonus** How to find your network interface name via GUI

The following command lines can be used to connect and disconnect depending on the Wireless card, wireless security and wireless router settings. Before proceeding, make sure the network service is enabled (For cases where you might start Ubuntu using Recovery mode):

Depending on your Ubuntu Version, you would need to start it using one of the following way:

If using SystemD (since 14.10+):

```
sudo systemctl start networking
```

If using the Legacy init.d way: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

If using the Legacy Upstart way: `sudo service network-manager restart`

### Part 1: Wireless Routers with no password or WEP Key

For cases where the wireless router has no password or WEP security, do the following:

1. Open the terminal and lookup for the wireless connection:

   ```
   iwlist wlan0 s
   ```

   (The **s** is for Scan. **wlan0** is my wireless card but could be different for each user. Some have eth0, others wlan2.. You need `sudo` to execute this option.To find out the name of your wireless card simply type iwlist and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. This should autocomplete the line with the network card's name. You can also type `iwconfig` and find the name on the list that will show.)

   If you do not know the name of your wireless devices type: `iwconfig` which will show you your wired/wireless devices and their names. They might be something like wlan0, wlan1, eth1, eth2..
2. The lookup will show you all possible Access Points (AP) visible to you. After you see your router in the list try to connect to it:

   If it does not have a password do the following:

   ```
   iwconfig wlan0 essid NAME_OF_ACCESS_POINT
   ```

   For example

   ```
   iwconfig wlan0 essid CYREX
   ```

   after that, make sure to use `dhclient` so you can get a dynamic IP in case you don't get assigned one by the router. That should leave you connected to the CYREX router.

   If it has a password then do:

   ```
   iwconfig wlan0 essid CYREX key PASSWORD
   ```

   That should connect using the PASSWORD you gave there.

   Again, do `dhclient` after connecting to make sure you get an IP assigned.
3. Making sure you are correctly connected is always good so execute `iwconfig` to make sure your wireless card is connected to the SSID you mentioned above. It should show your device connected and the IP assigned to you. If it does not and gives you an error like **Interface doesn't support scanning** try the following 2 options:

   - Test if your interface is UP: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`
   - Try adding `sudo` when doing the scan: `sudo iwlist wlan0 s`
   - Try bringing the device down and then back up:

     ```
     sudo ifconfig wlan0 down  
     sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
     ```

### Part 2: Wireless Routers with WPA or WPA2 security Key

For cases where the wireless router has a WPA/WPA2 password there are a few ways of doing this. I will mention the 2 most popular ones::

1. Open the terminal and lookup for the wireless connection:

   ```
   iwlist wlan0 s
   ```

   (The **s** is for Scan. **wlan0** is my wireless card but could be different for each user. Some have eth0, others wlan2.. You need `sudo` to execute this option. To find out the name of your wireless card simply type iwlist and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. This should autocomplete the line with the network card's name. You can also type `iwconfig` and find the name on the list that will show.)

   If you do not know the name of your wireless devices type: `iwconfig` which will show you your wired/wireless devices and their names. They might be something like wlan0, wlan1, eth1, eth2..
2. The lookup will show you all possible Access Points (AP) visible to you. After you see your router in the list try to connect to it:

#### Part 2.1 WPA-SUPPLICANT GUIDE: Connecting to a WPA Router with wpa_supplicant

1. Type the following in the terminal (Assuming you have the `wpasupplicant` package installed which installs all the needed commands we will use here):

   ```
   wpa_passphrase SSID PASSWORD > CONFIG_FILE
   ```

   Example: `wpa_passphrase Virus LinuxFTW > wpa.conf`

   Where **Virus** is the name of my router,**LinuxFTW** is my password and `wpa.conf` is the file where I want to store all of this information in. Note that you can save the file in another place, many users save the file in `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` instead of `wpa.conf`. The data of the wpa.conf file should be something like this:

   ```
   network={  
           ssid="Virus"  
           #psk="LinuxFTW"  
           psk=1d538d505f48205589ad25b2ca9f52f9cbb67687e310c58a8dd940ccc03fbfae  
   }
   ```
2. Up to this point, we should know the name of our wireless card interface (eg: Wlan0, eth2, Wlan2...). We now need to know which Driver is in use. for this we type:

   ```
   wpa_supplicant
   ```

   It should show us a lot of information, but there will be a section called **Drivers* which shows all available drivers (These are available when compiling `wpa_supplicant`). In my case it is like this:

   ```
   drivers:  
     wext = Linux wireless extensions (generic)  
     nl80211 = Linux nl80211/cfg80211  
     wired = Wired Ethernet driver  
     none = no driver (RADIUS server/WPS ER)
   ```

   The whole list is hostap, hermes, madwifi, wext, broadcom, wired, roboswitch, bsd, ndis. This can change depending on how `wpa_supplicant` was compiled, but the one that shows for me should be similar to the one on your system. Most users will select the `wext` driver.
3. So now that we have our wireless interface card name and the driver name, we proceed to connect to it using the already created configuration file using the following format:

   ```
   wpa_supplicant -iINTERFACE_NAME -cCONFIGURATION_FILE -DDRIVER_NAME
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext
   ```

   Where `-i` is your interface card's name, `-c` is where your configuration file is and `-D` is the name of the driver you will be using to connect. If it connects correctly, then we press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel it and then execute the line again but this time we send it to the background with `-B` so we can continue to use the terminal:

   ```
   wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext
   ```

   After that simply do a `sudo dhclient wlan0` to get an IP from the router.
4. Some users have reported removing the Hash and leaving only the password in the config, for example:

   ```
        network={  
               ssid="Virus"  
               psk="LinuxFTW"  
       }
   ```

   Others have added the ssid_scan to the config file:

   ```
       network={  
               ssid="Virus"
               scan_ssid=1  
               #psk="LinuxFTW"  
               psk=1d538d505f48205589ad25b2ca9f52f9cbb67687e310c58a8dd940ccc03fbfae  
       }
   ```

   Or even adding the Key type:

   ```
       network={  
               ssid="Virus"
               scan_ssid=1  
               key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
               #psk="LinuxFTW"  
               psk=1d538d505f48205589ad25b2ca9f52f9cbb67687e310c58a8dd940ccc03fbfae  
       }
   ```

   More information about this in `man wpa_supplicant.conf`

#### Part 2.2 NETWORK MANAGER GUIDE: Connecting to a WPA Router with Network Manager

The good thing about network manager is that it comes with a couple of nice scripts and tools. Two of these are `nmcli` and `create_connection` (Neat Python 3 script) which we will use in this case.

1. After doing the steps mentioned previously to find your router's SSID name (Remember the part about `iwlist` above) we do the following:

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/checkbox/scripts/create_connection -S SECURITY_TYPE -K PASSWORD SSID_NAME
   ```

   Where **SECURITY** is the type of security the Router uses (WPA, WEP), **PASSWORD** is.. well..the password and SSID_NAME is the SSID Name of the Router. For example:

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/checkbox/scripts/create_connection -S wpa -K LinuxFTW Virus
   ```

   Will create a connection for Network Manager which should look something like this:

   ```
     $ sudo /usr/share/checkbox/scripts/create_connection -S wpa -K LinuxFTW Virus
     [sudo] password for cyrex: 
     Connection Virus registered
     Connection Virus activated.
   ```
2. After this, you should get an IP assigned from the router. If not simply do `sudo dhclient wlan0` (Assuming wlan0 is the name of your interface). You can also check your network manager's connections using nmcli like this: `nmcli c` which should show something like this:

   ```
    $ nmcli c
     NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
     Xcentral                  f51a5a64-8a91-47d6-897c-28efcd84d2b0   802-11-wireless   Fri 22 Mar 2013 02:25:54 PM VET   
     Realtek                   9ded7740-ad29-4c8f-861f-84ec4da87f8d   802-3-ethernet    Tue 05 Mar 2013 01:18:31 AM VET   
     Intel                     e25b1fd8-c4ff-41ac-a6bc-22620296f01c   802-3-ethernet    Fri 05 Apr 2013 10:04:05 PM VET   
     Virus                     3f8ced55-507b-4558-a70b-0d260441f570   802-11-wireless   Tue 09 Apr 2013 06:31:10 AM VET
   ```

I mention the Network Manager's way because there are a couple of cases where using  `wpa_supplicant` will simply not work (Problems between router and wireless card, security issues, etc..). In my case, all attempts to use `wpa_supplicant` on one PC did not work, but in another it worked the first time I tried. So am posting both methods to help on each case and to make it easier for users to decide which one they want.

### Part 3: Easy Connection via nmcli

Although we have talked about the ways to connect to it without a network manager, there is also the case of using nmcli (CLI version of the network manager) when it applies. To do this, we do the following:

1. Check to see which ESSID we can see:

   ```
   nmcli dev wifi
   ```
2. Verify the name of the ESSID and we proceed on using it on the next line including the password needed for it (This includes WEP and WPA type passwords):

   ```
   nmcli dev wifi connect ESSID_NAME password ESSID_PASSWORD
   ```

   Here is an example of me connecting to the ESSID Linux5G

   [image: screenshot]

   If you have multiple wireless devices on your computer, you can specify which one to use using the `ifname` parameter like so:

   nmcli dev wifi connect ESSID_NAME password ESSID_PASSWORD ifname WIRELESS_DEVICE_NAME

   For example in my case the name of the device is `wlp9s0` so I would use this line to specify the device that I will use to connect with:

   [image: screenshot]

More information about nmcli can be obtained by using the help parameter. For example if you wanted to know about about `nmcli dev` you would type `nmcli dev help`. If you wanted to know more about `nmcli dev wifi`, you would type `nmcli dev wifi help` and so on.

### Part 4: Disconnecting from a Wireless Router

There are several ways of accomplishing this:

- Disconnect by "force": `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`

  This will turn your wireless card interface off (Driver turns off). To turn in on simply type `ifconfig wlan0 up` followed by a `sudo dhclient wlan0`. It will still show as connected if viewed by Network Manager but there will actually be no connection to the router. Trying to `ping` will throw an `connect: Network is unreachable` error.
- Release the DHCP IP: `sudo dhclient -r wlan0`

  Remember to do `sudo dhclient wlan0` to assign yourself an IP again.
- Disconnect using Network Manager: `nmcli nm enable false`

  Where nm is the parameter of nmcli that manages and sets Network Manager's states. The option `enable` can be **true** or **false**, meaning if set to **false**, all network connections managed by Network Manager will be disconnected. note that nmcli does not need root permissions.

To see the status of Network Manager type `nmcli nm`, it should show something similar to this:

```
      $ nmcli nm
      RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
      running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
```

Another way of turning the Connection On or Off (Connecting/Disconnecting) is by doing the following:

```
nmcli c down id NAME` - Will disconnect the connection NAME  

nmcli c up id NAME` - Will connect the connection NAME
```

### Part 5: Deleting a Connection

To delete an existing connection is fairly easy. First type in the terminal:

```
nmcli c
```

It will output something like this:

```
$ nmcli c
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Realtek                   9ded7740-ad29-4c8f-861f-84ec4da87f8d   802-3-ethernet    Tue 05 Mar 2013 01:18:31 AM VET   
PrivateSys                86b2b37d-4835-44f1-ba95-46c4b747140f   802-11-wireless   Sun 21 Apr 2013 07:52:57 PM VET   
pepe                      9887664b-183a-45c0-a81f-27d5d0e6d9d8   802-11-wireless   Thu 18 Apr 2013 02:43:05 AM VET   
Virus                     3f8ced55-507b-4558-a70b-0d260441f570   802-11-wireless   Tue 16 Apr 2013 11:33:24 AM VET   
Intel                     e25b1fd8-c4ff-41ac-a6bc-22620296f01c   802-3-ethernet    Sun 21 Apr 2013 08:12:29 PM VET   
Xcentral                  f51a5a64-8a91-47d6-897c-28efcd84d2b0   802-11-wireless   Fri 22 Mar 2013 02:25:54 PM VET
```

Now let us say we want to delete **Xcentral**, we then proceed with the following command:

```
nmcli c delete id Xcentral
```

After doing it should look something like this:

```
$ nmcli c delete id Xcentral
$ nmcli c
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Realtek                   9ded7740-ad29-4c8f-861f-84ec4da87f8d   802-3-ethernet    Tue 05 Mar 2013 01:18:31 AM VET   
PrivateSys                86b2b37d-4835-44f1-ba95-46c4b747140f   802-11-wireless   Sun 21 Apr 2013 07:52:57 PM VET   
pepe                      9887664b-183a-45c0-a81f-27d5d0e6d9d8   802-11-wireless   Thu 18 Apr 2013 02:43:05 AM VET   
Virus                     3f8ced55-507b-4558-a70b-0d260441f570   802-11-wireless   Tue 16 Apr 2013 11:33:24 AM VET   
Intel                     e25b1fd8-c4ff-41ac-a6bc-22620296f01c   802-3-ethernet    Sun 21 Apr 2013 08:12:29 PM VET
```

All connections are stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

If I were to look in that folder right now I would see the following files:

```
$ ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
Intel  pepe  PrivateSys  Realtek  Virus
```

This is only in case you wish to edit/delete/add a connection by hand.

### Part 6: Automatic connection when login in

For cases where you would like to login automatically to a wireless router here are the steps:

1. Open the `interface` file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
   ```
2. Add the following information (Assuming your interface is called wlan0):

   ```
   auto wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet static
   address ASSIGNED_IP
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway THE_GATEWAY
   wireless-essid YOURSSID
   wireless-key WIRELESSKEY_HERE
   ```
3. Save the file and reboot computer. Note that this will be saved on a plain text file which can be accessed from the same computer.

### Bonus: Find your wireless connection's name GUI Style

1. Click on the Network Manager and go to **Connection Information**

   [image: screenshot]
2. Go to the Tab that holds your wireless card

   [image: screenshot]

In this image, this network card is named **eth1** (Inside the parenthesis) but this can be different for each user. Normally it would be a wlan (Like wlan0, wlan1, wlan2...) but it can also be eth1, eth2, etc.. So you need to see what name it has.

Another way to find the name quickly is by typing `iwconfig` which will show all the wireless network card available.

Comment: If have found another command line way to find the name of the wireless interface. after typing `iwlist` press tab twice and the terminal will automatically type the name of the interface after `iwilst`

Comment: I could correctly guess the author looking at the completeness of the answer.

Comment: @douglaswalrath You would use quotes, as in "sugar fairy"

Comment: Thanks for the extensive guide! I wonder if there are other ways to link to a wireless on startup without having the password written in plain text in a file... Do you have any idea?

Comment: I could think of a script that can only be executed by a specific user and that it grabs the password from an encrypted location that only the specific user could read, then stores the password on a temp environment variable which is then send as input to the wireless command, after connection is successful, the temp environment variable is removed. Am just thinking out loud about other methods.

Comment: @Michele this other answer gives guidance on how to prevent the password from being saved on the history http://askubuntu.com/a/279333/237654

Comment: I followed the steps, but receive `ioctl [SIOCSIWENCODEEXT] Invalid argument` error when I run `wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext -d`

Comment: @PHPLearner Did you verify that the .conf file had the proper syntax. Typically that error means that the .conf file had something not correctly written in it.

Comment: The initial use of wpa_supplicant produces an error for me--not the desired output for a config file.

Comment: For those who, like me, searches for `create_connection` script in Ubuntu 14.04: it is no longer exists in `checkbox` package, but appears in `plainbox-provider-checkbox` package under `/usr/lib/2013.com.canonical.certification:checkbox/bin/create_connection`

Comment: For others like myself or @PHPLearner who have the `ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]` error, I found that a reboot of my device solved that error. As soon as I rebooted I was connected to the network with an IP address assigned.

Answer (score 44):

It's pretty easy if you know how to do it.

Show available wlan access points:

```
nmcli dev wifi
```

Connect with access point:

```
nmcli dev wifi connect $ACCESS_POINT password $PASSWORD
```

Comment: This is far better than the up-voted answer from Alvarado, which did not work in my case (Linux Mint 17.1). But this is pretty simple and just WORKS!

Comment: worked for me on Linux Mint 17

Comment: This is the winning answer for me. Just quick, easy and secure. Thank you!.

Comment: @Thorben IMHO this is not the accepted answer, because `network manager command line interface` doesn't answer the original question `How to connect without a network manager`.

Comment: +1 because this answer, although not applying to the question, would help someone when on recovery mode and save time. Excellent work user82110.

Comment: Works perfectly on mint mate 18 !

Comment: also works on Fedora 31!

Comment: To turn the wireless on first, do `nmcli networking on`. To turn it off, do `nmcli networking off`.

Comment: Does this solution work without x-windows installed? I haven't tried that, but it works on a terminal emulator running on Cinnamon on Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 13):

wicd comes with 2 command line utilities: wicd-curses and wicd-cli (they may require a separate install) 
wicd-curse lets you configure/connect disconnect to networks (wired or wireless) interactively, wicd-cli offers the same functionality but through command line options only (useful for scripts) I use it in a cron job to work around some autoreconnect bugs:

```
wicd-cli -y -c -m MY_NETWORK_SSID
```

Also you can "just" have a wpa_supplicant configuration something like:

/etc/network/interface :

```
auto wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet dhcp 
wpa-conf /etc/wpa.conf
```

and (as a WPA example) 
/etc/wpa.conf:

```
network={
  ssid="MY_NETWORK_SSID"
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA_PSK
  pairwise=CCMP_TKIP
  group=CCMP_TKIP
  psk="my network key in the clear"
}
```

there are a lot of considerations to this, of which the security concern of having the preshared key in clear text (wpa_supplicant can let you present an encrypted or maybe just obfuscated key, check the man page), also making that file owned and readable only by root is a mitigation.

I *think* having several network sections would enable to connect several networks, by order of priority.

Comment: wicd is not installed by default, not sure if it compatible with network manager.

Comment: it;s incompatible. YOu can follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Answer (score 5):

I use `wicd-curses`, which I find to be the easiest user interface by far.

[image: wicd-curses]

You need to use the <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow key `->`) to set configurations; everything else is obvious from the on-screen instructions.

Of course you need to find some way of getting on the internet without `wicd`; I'm assuming you have already solved that or else you wouldn't be posting.

*(This is not timely to the OP, just posting for posterity since this question still comes up on Google. To the google-seekers: if you're reading this from a café or friend's computer or something, maybe you can use a wire somewhere to get `wicd-curses` installed with `sudo apt-get install wicd-curses`; then make sure you test it out on a network that's known to work before leaving!)*

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for Ubuntu 18.04+ without using NetworkManager

Working on a RasPi with freshly installed Ubuntu Server 20.04: NetworkManager (`nmcli` / `nmtui` etc) isn't already installed, so a more manual approach may be helpful, at least to start with.

Ubuntu's underlying networking looks to be handled by `netplan` from version 18.04 onwards, so this is what needs to be configured for those versions. A useful [walk-through](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line) provides an answer; in short (e.g.),

Determine the name of your wifi interface,

```
$ ip a
```

(typically it's `wlan0` - look for this in the output from `ip a`). Now edit `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`,

```
$ sudo vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

(other editors are available etc) and add a `wifis:` section as below,

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "network-name-here":
                    password: "wifi-password-here"
            dhcp4: true
```

enable this with,

```
$ sudo netplan apply
```

finally check that your wifi is now up by looking for the `wlan0` interface and corresponding IP addresses,

```
$ ip a
```

Comment: I followed till the step regarding editing the .yaml file which was ``01-network-manager-all.yaml`` in my case. After running ``sudo netplan apply`` , I do not get any errors, but running ``$ ip a `` just results with the lan config, ``wlo1`` it anything similar does not pop up. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, currently on tty1 because something went wrong after i changed my display drivers and i no longer have gui, to download the newer drivers here, i need internet.