# Can't configure wireless now that WPA2 is enabled!

Tags: 10.04, networking, wireless, ubuntu-netbook, broadcom

I had removed network-manager as soon as I installed Ubuntu 10.04.

Earlier I used to do the following to connect (successfully) on command line:
`iwconfig eth2 essid NASA`
 `dhclient eth2`

Now that WPA2 encryption is enabled, I tried this, but failed:
`iwconfig eth2 essid NASA key hunter2`
`dhclient eth2`

with error:
`Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    invalid argument "hunter2"`

Where am I going wrong?

`lspci` gives:
`02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4727 (rev 01)`

`lshw -C network` gives:

`*-network

       description: Wireless interface

       product: Broadcom Corporation

       vendor: Broadcom Corporation

       physical id: 0

       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0

       logical name: eth2

       version: 01

       serial: 78:e4:00:2e:54:28

       width: 64 bits

       clock: 33MHz

       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless

       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.60.48.36   ip=192.1.0.20 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

       resources: irq:17 memory:56000000-56003fff`

Edit 1: As suggested by CYREX, I tried WPA directions given in:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188
In the command:
`sudo wpa_supplicant -D wext -i eth2 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`
I used wext as the driver.

When I run this command, the following happens:
`Trying to associate with 00:24:b2:39:f4:c6 (SSID='NASA' freq=2462 MHz)  ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Device or resource busy

Association request to the driver failed

Associated with 00:1b:2f:a8:da:cc

WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:1b:2f:a8:da:cc

[PTK=TKIP GTK=TKIP] CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:1b:2f:a8:da:cc

completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]`

I tried both his WPA1 and WPA2 stuff. In either case `iwconfig eth2` gives `Encryption key: off`.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned as there hasn't been any activity for a longer period of time. I'm voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I made this one: [How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-to-wireless-network-manually-in-terminal-without-using-network-m)

But i think it won't work since i later found out that when you put a WPA key, the whole thing gets a "little" complicated. Not so easy as iwconfi wlan0 key s:password for like WEP security. I then found out this HUGE post which has in detail information that worked in my case for WPA and WPA2 using PSK (At least in my case) I hope it helps you too:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188

NOTE: Make sure your card supports WPA. Happen to one of my students that he spend a week trying this and it did not work since his card did not support WPA (It did not even have anything WPA related).

More Specific link about WPA2 -> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=607410
Good luck, let me know how it went.

Comment: I tried WPA directions given in: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188

In the command:
`sudo wpa_supplicant -D wext -i eth2 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`  
I used wext as the driver. When I run this command, the following happens:  
`Trying to associate with 00:24:b2:39:f4:c6 (SSID='NASA' freq=2462 MHz)
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Device or resource busy
Association request to the driver failed
Associated with 00:1b:2f:a8:da:cc
WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:1b:2f:a8:da:cc [PTK=TKIP GTK=TKIP]
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:1b:2f:a8:da:cc completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]`

Comment: BTW, I tried both his WPA1 and WPA2 stuff. In either case `iwconfig eth2` gives `Encryption key: off`.

Comment: @avinash Add all this information to your question please so it doesn't get buried in the comments.

Comment: @Luis Alvardo thanks for making these guides I was searching for some information and reached your hard work