# How to establish wireless connection from command line?

Tags: networking, command-line, console, wireless

Can someone please tell me how I can establish connection to my WiFi network from the command line? (My desktop GUI [is fried](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59631/how-to-recover-from-uninstall-of-ubuntu-desktop).)

I've tried the following:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_NAME
sudo iwconfig wlan0 key s:NETWORK_PASSWORD
```

However, the second command (to set the password) fails with an error message reading: "Invalid argument".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can connect with this command even from the true (not emulated) terminal:

```
nmcli con up id 'my.net.work'
```