# Connecting to wireless networks from command line

Tags: wireless, command-line, wpa-supplicant

I need to write a shell script which connects to one of the two available wi-fi connections. One is a un secure connection and the other is secure connection.
My question has 2 parts-

1. How to connect to the un-secure (un-encrypted and no password required) connection from command line (or by executing a shell script) when I'm connected to the secure connection?

   I followed the steps in http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-troubleshoot-wireless-network-connection-in-ubuntu.html for in-secure connection. I put all the commands in a script and executed it (I made sure that interface name and essid are correct)

   ```
   sudo dhclient -r wlan0
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
   sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "UAPublic"
   sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Managed
   sudo dhclient wlan0
   ```

   But nothing happens: I'm not disconnected from the current network and connected to the new one.
2. When I want to connect to the secure wi-fi network, I understand from https://askubuntu.com/a/138476/70665 that I need to use `wpa_supplicant`.
   But I enter a lot of details in the interface when I connect via UI

   - security : wpa and wpa2 enterprise
   - Authentication : PEAP
   - CA certificate : Equifax...
   - PEAP version : automatic
   - inner authentication : MSCHAPv2
   - username :
   - password :

How to use wpa_supplicant to mention all these details in the command line? The conf file

```
network={
        ssid="ssid_name"
        psk="password"
}
```

doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you're using Ubuntu Desktop as you didn't specify otherwise.

You can create a wireless network configuration that will be managed by Network Manager by creating files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. Look at existing files to see how the format looks like.

Once the connection is created, you can use the `nmcli` command to manage NetworkManager from the command line, doing things such as enabling, disabling and querying connections.

Incidentally, the System Testing tool (checkbox) has a script that does exactly this: creates a connection and enables it, with parameters that you supply on the command line.

For instance, this creates a connection to the open "duck" network:

```
sudo /usr/share/checkbox/scripts/create_connection duck
```

This will create a connection to a network using WPA2 security, with "wings" password:

```
sudo /usr/share/checkbox/scripts/create_connection -S wpa -K wings duck
```

The script is written in Python so it should be easy for you to look at and adapt to your needs.

The script's help says this:

```
Usage: create_connection [options] SSID

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -S SECURITY, --security=SECURITY
                        The type of security to be used by the connection.
                        One of wpa and wep. No security will be used if
                        nothing is specified.
  -K KEY, --key=KEY     The encryption key required by the router.
  -U UUID, --uuid=UUID  The uuid to assign to the connection for use by
                        NetworkManager. One will be generated if not
                        specified here.
  -R RETRIES, --retries=RETRIES
                        The number of times to attempt bringing up the
                        connection until it is confirmed as active.
  -I INTERVAL, --interval=INTERVAL
                        The time to wait between attempts to detect the
                        registration of the connection.
```