# how to connect to wireless network through terminal

Tags: 12.04, wireless, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect to a WPA wifi network using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line)
>   [Connecting to wireless networks from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150972/connecting-to-wireless-networks-from-command-line)

I am a newbie to ubuntu 12.04.pls tell me how to connect to wireless network via terminal.I use a tata photon plus usb model.

How do i know that my internet is connected?(from terminal)
I need to install,and update some packages.Somehow I couldn't do them through browser, because my system is running in low graphics.I need to fix a lot,for which i need to connect to internet.

Answer (score 0):

First list your wireless devices

**`sudo lshw -C network`**

*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@06:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 03
serial: 00:12:17:35:17:10
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ndiswrapper+lsbcmnds driverversion=1.48rc1+Cisco-Linksys ,LLC.,02/1 ip=192.168.1.101 latency=64 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11g
resources: iomemory:3c000000-3c001fff irq:11

If the card is DISABLED it will show it.
Run this command where eth0 is your network card

**`sudo ifconfig eth0 up`**

That command will turn on the wireless card.

Comment: your answers helps -already- half the way. I think it would be great and maybe help further if you added some insights to use `iwconfig` `ìwlist` and `wpa_supplicant`, which are usedful/necessary. Especially when wanting to connect to a wireless router that uses some encryption. I assume the question asker would need more than just enabling the device at least the user wrote "connect wireless" in the question