# How to reinstall network manager without internet access?

Tags: network-manager

Unfortunately, I uninstalled `network-manager-gnome` using `sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager`. I was trying to reinstall it from but without internet connection I cannot do so. What is the solution for this?

Comment: do you have access to other machines with same OS of this machine?

Comment: It is dangerous piece of software at very bad state ans should be avoided at all costs. So do not use it. NEVER

Answer (score 65):

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

then you will have internet and you can use...

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Comment: Note: this is trickier if you have WiFi, but if you can remove your WiFi password (using a second laptop), then the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/294320/67747 get simple enough that this worked for me: `sudo iwconfig <device> essid <access_point_name> && sudo dhclient <device>`  I did not need `ifconfig <device> up` or similar in my case.

Comment: Would work, if you can get access to internet with cabel. But than should make reboot

Comment: I love you so much

Comment: "Cannot find device eth0" :(

Comment: if you run `sudo iwconfig` you will see the devices. in my case I did not have `eth0` for the name of my wired connection.

Comment: or run `sudo lshw -C network` and find the logical name. In my case I was using mobile hotspot via USB, so it was `enxc6b3013d3956`

Comment: What a genius trick, thank you

Comment: Wow, that is amazing. thank you!

Comment: This was perfect answer. I have looking everywhere for 5 hours.

Answer (score 23):

If you've recently upgraded your network manager you can use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager`, but this only works if the package is still in your Apt cache (`/var/cache/apt/archives/`). I'm guessing you haven't so you'll have to do things the long way, but I thought I'd throw that in just in case.

1. Boot a Ubuntu live CD in "Try without installing". Make sure you are connected to the internet.
2. In terminal type:

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /<chrootlocation>/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /<chrootlocation>/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys /<chrootlocation>/sys
   sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /<chrootlocation>/etc/resolv.conf
   sudo chroot /<chrootlocation>
   ```

   You will need to replace `<chrootlocation>` with the appropriate location of your Ubuntu install, typically the label of the partition it's installed on. The partition must also be mounted so that you can access it.
3. Edit your `/etc/resolve.conf` and add at least one `nameserver`:

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Google Public DNS
   ```
4. In terminal type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install network-manager
   ```

   If you don't you'll likely get an unable to connect error.
5. In terminal type `exit`. This exits you from the chroot environment.
6. In terminal type `sudo reboot` to reboot your computer.

Comment: there needs an internet connection for `sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: there would be in the chroot. the reason he has no internet is because he uninstalled the network manager, the livecd will have network manager installed so he can use that to connect and install to the other ubuntu installation.

Comment: The way I read the question is that the user is on a computer that is normally connected to the internet, but because he uninstalled the network-manager he's currently unable to connect to the internet. Using a livecd get's around this issue. Quote: "I was trying to reinstall it from but without internet connection i cannot do so". Perhaps I've read it wrong?

Comment: Also bind the `run` directory, otherwise you will probably be getting `unable to resolve hostname` errors: `sudo mount --bind /run /chrootlocation/run`

Comment: This didn't work for me - although the live CD has access to the network, as soon as I chroot the network access (for the chrooted command line) vanishes.

Comment: Worked also for me who had uninstalled dnsmasq-base. Thanks

Comment: This is perfect; worked great with Ubuntu 18.04.3, and was able to restore my network. Thanks!

Comment: I had an issue while I'm doing upgrade in my Ubuntu 22.04 and network got broken somehow. Then this woked and saved me from spending hours for setting up my environment from scratch. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

This answer assumes that you had internet access before losing network-manager or any other packages.

### Live CD/DVD/USB

Create a bootable Ubuntu CD/DVD or USB stick, boot from it and select "Try Ubuntu without installing". Once you get to the Ubuntu desktop, open a terminal.

### Root Partition

You need to find out your root partition on your Ubuntu installation. On a standard Ubuntu installation, the root partition is "/dev/sda1", but it may be different for you. To figure out what's the root partition, run the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will display a list of hard disks and partitions from which you'll have to figure out which one is the root partition. Below in step 3, ROOT-PARTITION is the root partition you just found, for example /dev/sda2 in my case.

### Chroot Into Your Root Partition

To make sure a certain partition is the root partition, you can mount it. So let's mount the root partition along with the /sys, /proc, /run and /dev partitions and enter chroot:

```
sudo mount ROOT-PARTITION /mnt
for i in /sys /proc /run /dev /dev/pts; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/
sudo chroot /mnt
```

If you get an error about resolv.conf being identical when copying it, just ignore it. Copying resolv.conf gets the network working, at least for me (using DHCP).

### Update/Install Packages

Now you can update the system - in the same terminal, type:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

If you have problems on the last step, make sure your sources are correct in /etc/apt/sources.list - in the same terminal, type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Since you've chrooted into your Ubuntu installation, the changes you make affect it and not the Live CD, as long as all changes are made in the same terminal session.

Reboot when finished and remove the Live CD. If this answer fixes your problem, please mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: I had a crash on my network-manager on Ubuntu 14.04 and this work for me!
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This worked, although I had to do a `apt-get -f install` (nothing else) to get dependencies(?) to go in. Then the `apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome`. I had hosed my networking by removing `wpasupplicant` which wanted to remove everything network, but a reinstall of `wpasupplicant` didn't reinstall the network stuff.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Confirmed working on Ubuntu 16.04 Unity

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager
```

The above command will purge all the packages that was related to the service `network-manager`.You can download all   packages as .deb file using a Ubuntu Live disk and then install it to your original OS.

- First boot from a Ubuntu Live disk.
- Once you go there open a terminal and run the below command,

  ```
  sudo apt-get download network-manager*
  ```
- This will download all the network-manager packages to the home directory.
- Now copy all the `.deb` packages to a folder in that pen drive or other partitions in your HDD and then reboot to your system.
- Once you go there open terminal and do the following:

  ```
  cd /path/to/the/directory/where/.deb/files/are/located
  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
  ```
- The above command will install all the `.deb` files.
- Now restart your network-manager by running `sudo service network-manager restart`

Now you have the package `network-manager-gnome` running again.

Comment: The OP has asked for a solution where he can do this **without** access to internet.

Comment: The OP has no Internet due to the removing of the `network-manager-gnome` package, but this doesn't mean that he has no Internet. Also be aware that using Live CD will not rely on the host package so he'll get access to Internet

Comment: Remove network-manager, now how connect to download packages? :-/ thanks for the additional problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just solved this same problem, follow these simple steps:

1. Download network-manager in a device having internet connection from
   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/
   I used **network-manager_1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb** for ubuntu16.04
2. Then transfer this file using USB or phone etc.
3. `$ sudo dpkg -i network-manager_1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb`

It may happen that the wifi shortcut might be missing on the top, for that just use this command

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and then a normal restart of your machine.

Done :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm in Ubuntu 16.04. Easiest solution.:)

Comment: If you do not have access to a USB drive (e.x. you are on vacation and you forgot it), then you can use the SD-card found in just about every camera to transfer over the file so long as both computers have SD-card slots.

Comment: DO NOT RUN THE APT AUTOFIX!!! It uninstalled the Cinnamon package from my  Linux Mint computer and led me down a path towards reinstalling my Linux Mint from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

Follow official Ubuntu communuty LiveCdRecovery Update Failure section:   (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery):

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
3. Run:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
4. Add OpenDNS name servers to your `/etc/resolv.conf` to access the network after chroot:

   ```
   nameserver 208.67.222.222
   nameserver 208.67.220.220
   ```
5. Run:

   ```
   apt-get install network-manager
   ```

This helped to fix the same issue on my Ubunty 14.04LTS

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on 20.04 though /dev/sda1 was the live USB and I had to change that to the correct partition where the ubuntu root partition was installed. I had / and /home on different partitions.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm a little late on this but I just ran into this same problem. I installed arping (sudo apt-get install arping) which removed iputils-arping, network-manager, and network-manager-gnome. I edited the /etc/network/interface file to setup a manual IP for eth0.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# below are my changes

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    gateway y.y.y.y
    netmask z.z.z.z
    network a.a.a.a
    broadcast b.b.b.b
    dns-nameserver c.c.c.c d.d.d.d
```

Change x, y, z, a, c, and d to your network settings. I then ran "sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0" to restart the interface. This allowed my to reinstall network manager (sudo apt-get install network-manager). I had to purge the arping package I installed before network manager would reinstall. Then start network manager (sudo service network-manager start). Once I had network manager running I changed /etc/network/interface back to default (and kept a copy of the manual change just in case). Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer assumes that the reason you cannot access the internet is because you uninstalled "network-manager", and that normally the computer is connnected to the internet. However on the off chance that I read your question wrong, and this is in fact a computer that isn't ever connected to the internet you will need to use this answer instead though it will be more time consuming.

Step #1 = On another computer (It can be running Windows, doesn't matter), go to "http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/network-manager". (This link assumes you are using Ubuntu 12.04, if not you will need to find the link appropriate to your version).

Step #2 = At the bottom of the web page there is a link for "amd64" and "i386", click on the approriate one. I'm using amd64 so my steps will assume that.

Step #3 = On the new page there are a bunch of mirror links that are direct download links for "network-manager_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb". Pick a link, and download the .deb file.

Step #4 = On the first url I provided it also lists the dependencies for network-manager. You may have some of these still installed, but for the ones you don't you will need to download them as well by visiting their page and selecting a mirror.

Step #5 = Once you've downloaded all the .debs you will be needing transfer them to the Ubuntu computer and put them in "/var/cache/apt/archives". You will need root privileges to do this which can be achieved with "gksu nautilus /var/cache/apt/archives". You could also use dpkg to install them, but it won't tell if you've forgetten a dependency so I'm not going to get into how to use that.

Step #6 = In terminal type "sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager".

Comment: If this is a computer that isn't ever connected to the internet, then what would you need network-manager for anyway? The answer is connecting to a local intranet to access resources such as printers or scanners, or other local services.

Answer (score 1):

A newbies successful answer 16.04LTS
Was having trouble with network manager slowing/disconnecting with new internet provider
Rashly, decided to switch back to wicd and removed network manager via command line
Found couldn't get wicd working (stupidly wasn't finding any networks anyway)

Solution
First downloaded appropriate network manager deb file on another computer 
(32bit/i386 for me)(mine was network-manager_1.2.2-OubuntuO,16.04.4_i386.deb)
moved file across to ubuntu system laptop using memory card

took time to find out the following - simply double clicked on transferred deb file (on my desktop) and it installed itself (had major problems using the command line)

internet now connected - but not perfect - no icon

so I updated using command:     sudo apt-get update
Then install NetworkManager:   sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager

Once rebooted, t
his appears to have given me back my icon and full network manager operation

Hope this is helpful for you as it was for me
step 1 - get the correct networ-manager deb file from packages website
(mine was network-manager_1.2.2-OubuntuO,16.04.4_i386.deb)
move it to you ubuntu computer - double click it and install
step 2 update and (re)install network manager via command line/terminal, and get missing parts, problems and updates sorted.
good luck

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to install network-manager without the internet.  I got the idea from another post to  add the cdrom: [Ubuntu install DVD/CD] to the software sources in Software and Updates on the 'Other Software' tab.  The cdrom source was already listed but not checked so I checked it.  Then I used Synaptic Package Manager to install 'network-manager'.  I guess I could have used Ubuntu Software instead.  This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Ubuntu 20.04 installation. This was on a desktop machine, without WiFi. The dhclient thing did not work for me. So I managed to set a fixed IP. You need to know your router IP, and a free IP on your network (example done as root, `#` is the prompt)

1. First figure out what your device name is:

   ```
   # lshw -C network | grep "logical name"
   ```

   If you have multiple network ports, if you don't know which one to use experiment with each one.
2. Create a static IP

   ```
   # ip addr add 192.168.1.123/24 dev yourdevname
   ```

   where `yourdevname` is taken from the `lshw` logical name
3. Add a default gateway route

   ```
   # route add default gw 192.168.1.1
   ```

   Note that you need to know the IP of your router
4. Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add/change/set it to the following two lines (backup old file if you like)

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 9.9.9.9
   ```

   You can use different IP addresses if you know your DNS server IP. The above two listed should get you going.

That's it, hopefully you have full internet access again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out that I accidentally deleted `/etc/resolv.conf` and then got the same symptoms (`nslookup nba.com` doesn't work, but `nslookup nba.com 4.2.2.4` does work, when `4.2.2.4` was configured as my DNS server).

Restoring the file from a live USB solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Manually configure your ethernet card in /etc/network/interfaces and restart the networking service. Then apt-get update.

Comment: Manually configure your ethernet card in /etc/network/interfaces and restart the networking service. Then apt-get update.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.