# Google Chrome installation error

Tags: google-chrome

I used to use google chrome as default browser. One day I tried to use Google Cast extension to send my browser screen to chromecast, but I realized that my Chrome version was old. So I downloaded the debian package from google web site, but I ran on a dependency failure:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /home/plinio/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
    (Reading database ... 195156 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to replace google-chrome-stable 35.0.1916.114-1 (using .../google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement google-chrome-stable ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
     google-chrome-stable depends on libnss3 (>= 3.14.3); however:
      Version of libnss3 on system is 3.14.1-0ckbi1.93ubuntu.0.12.04.1.
    dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
    Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
    Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     google-chrome-stable
```

How to solve it? I had no success with Synaptc and Ubuntu Software Center as well.

[EDIT]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTE

[EDIT2]

Stack Exchange Mobile App is awesome! Thanks for it I could keep asking ubuntu even without network access in my workstation :D

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04LTS should have libnss3 3.15.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 available - do you get any errors after running `sudo apt-get install libnss3`, and if not, does chrome install OK afterwards?

Comment: @rocketman10404 It says `libnss3 is already the newest version`. After that, the issue remains.

Comment: So I entered `apt-get remove libnss3`. After saw outputs saying that a lot of packages were being removed, including network manager, I was wondering if that was a good idea. At least I could get chrome working. Hope I will get network back either =) So, others who are reading it, you must not remove that package. Solve it in another way.

Comment: I agree, you should find a way to upgrade without removing libnss3. Does synaptic's sources list show anything that might explain why apt doesn't see the newer version in the official repo?  Does trying `sudo apt-get update` first help anything?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: @rocketman10404 I tried that before remove libnss3 and got nothing.

Comment: @saiarcot895 I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTE. Question edited to contains this important info.

Comment: After all, with this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/422954/133964) I could get network back in my workstation.

Comment: Then, I got my desktop back doing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. Most amazing is that now I can cast to Chromecast using the new Chrome version :p Just to warn you: **you should not remove libnss3**.

Answer (score 1):

**`google-chrome-stable`** is availeble on [3rd Party Repository: Google](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable) Chrome (For Stable).

Follow the instruction for installation:

1. Add Key:

   ```
   wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Set repository:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
   ```
3. Install package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
   ```

Looks like you need to add the official google-chrome-stable in your Software Sources

Remove your google-chrome stable or fix with `sudo apt-get -f install`

Follow this: [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-14-04)