# No internet connection while installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, internet

Currently I am running Windows 7 on my PC. When I boot to Windows, it connects to the internet.

But when I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 and boot from the flash it shows `Disconnected - You are now offline`.

I am using wireless internet, and I also tried connecting directly from my router to my PC too, still I cannot connect to the internet.

Anyone has an idea how fix this very annoying problem?

the output of `ifconfig` is as bellow:

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 62:d5:10:5d:82:31  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1312 (1.3 KB)  TX bytes:1312 (1.3 KB)
```

Comment: We are going to need some more details to help you. Do you use a proxy when in windows?  Make and model of computer, Plug in a LAN cable open a terminal by pressing CTRL + ALT + T and enter `lspci; ifconfig` copy all the output and edit your question to include it.

Comment: Do you see available networks or not ? And what happens if you run this: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my hp dv6. After a lot of playing around with things and making sure the right drivers were installed, I tried checking my Bios settings and reset to default. Apparently that did the trick for me I guess when they install windows on laptops it changes something in the Bios.

Comment: my labtop is also hp dv6

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? when you boot up the computer keep hitting the esc button till it gives you a menu. When the menu is up hit F10 i believe to enter the bios menu. Then restore to default save and exit.

Comment: I did what you said but nothing was change, should I update my bios???

Comment: I have the latest bios from HP.

Comment: I updated my bios to the latest version, but still I couldn't connect to the internet

Answer (score -1):

Try connecting to the internet directly with an ethernet cable, not through the router. Just disconnect your router from the internet and plug the cable into your computer. Does it work? If it doesn't then there's a problem with the network-manager package.

I suggest to make the flash drive bootable again. Or you can install Ubuntu without connecting to the internet. You can connect later, after the installation. Let me know if it worked. If not i can help you fix your network-manager package

Comment: I inistall the ubuntu without connecting to the internet, but I still have problem to connect to the internet. what should i do now?

Comment: Ok, then you need to reinstall your network manager. This would be really easy if you had internet, but without internet things get a little bit more complicated.
Follow the steps in the second answer to this post:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access
Make sure to select the network manager package that corresponds to your version of Ubuntu. Good luck :D