# Unable to connect to VPN using gnome-network-manager

Tags: 14.04, gnome, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I originally wanted auto-connect VPN upon login, but after much trial and error and connection issues it looks like my network manager is corrupt.

When I try to connect Wifi by clicking Network Indicator -> VPN Connections -> (My VPN) I got no acknowledgment from the GUI that it could not connect.

When I did `tail /var/log/syslog`, I got:

```
Aug 25 19:59:01 NetworkManager[1041]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
Aug 25 20:00:07  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Aug 25 20:00:07 NetworkManager[1041]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 3544
Aug 25 20:00:07 NetworkManager[1041]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Aug 25 20:00:07 NetworkManager[1041]: <error> [1408993207.745279] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Aug 25 20:00:07 NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Policy set 'MY WIFI CONN' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Aug 25 20:00:13 NetworkManager[1041]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

Comment: Any trustworthy solutions for this issue, I am experiencing the same?

Comment: Not posting as an answer since I'm on a different distro, but... try rebooting. I just encountered the same and after rebooting it worked.

Answer (score 24):

In my case selecting the password option **Store the password for all users** got it working. All other options produce the mentioned error.

Comment: It's so jokey, but it works for me too.

Comment: Awesome! You save my day.

Comment: Terminal command `sudo nmcli connection modify "YOUR_VPN_NAME" +vpn.data "password-flags=0"`

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue and Plant Maven's answer was correct.

Instead of deleting the config files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` I moved them to another folder, so I could compare.

The only difference between the old config file and the new one is in a VPN connection I just re-created from scratch and it's the UUID.

No idea why the old file wouldn't work. I suspect it's something related to the keyring.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```

After running this command , I tried connecting to the vpn service, I was thankfully once again prompted for my vpn password and able to connect to the service.

After some weeks, I still have issues sometimes. When I log out and log in it resolves itself most of the time.
I am using WICD network manager also now, due to sometimes wifi stops working altogether !

Answer (score 2):

I just rm'd all files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ and restarted Ubuntu 14.04. Problem solved. I know it was the last software update because I updated and shutdown. The next time I started up Ubuntu, the network kept dropping connection.

Answer (score 2):

Please observe that the gnome Network Manager has changed and now when you edit connections you have a symbol to the right in the Password field that indicates how the password should be handled, "Store password only for this user", "Store the password for all users", Ask for this password every time and password is not required. You need to select "Ask for password every time" if you want the password question the second time 
This confused me a bit....

Comment: Nevermind, it stopped working and now I can't get my VPN to connect.

Answer (score 2):

I tried moving/deleting the connections in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, choosing the option "Store the password for all users" and "The password is not required" (for my VPN, it isn't), reinstalling network-manager, restarting Ubuntu, .. None of these worked.

My connections worked, but only periodically. I only tried through the `openvpn` command a few times, but it worked flawlessly.

To fix it, edit the connection and click

### `Advanced` -> tick `Accept authenticated packets from any address (Float)`

then save your connection. This was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this error although I encountered it after a week of flawless OpenVPN usage. I found an obscure idea to restart the dbus service in Ubuntu.

```
    sudo service dbus restart
```

It might be wise to concat another command to this command to restart your GUI since a power button reboot was necessary for me after I executed this command

Comment: This worked for me. The key was "No agents were available for this request" pointing to some IPC issue. It reloaded my KDE session and kicked me out but the VPN connection from NetworkManager worked fine after this

Answer (score 0):

[check this out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access) maybe you should purge network manager 
and reinstall the network-manager package you download, or from live cd

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was that the main ethernet interface was configured in /etc/network/interfaces , and then NetworkManager was refusing to manage it; I commented it out from /etc/network/interfaces and configured it in NetworkManager: then I could also use the VPN