# wifi and ethernet keep disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless

I don't know if this has been asked before, but the internet (ethernet and wifi) is constantly disconnected. I've checked the router, via other devices (such as cell phone and tablet) and access to internet is fine. Even when I boot Windows 7 on my computer it's able to connect and stay connected. When I'm running ubuntu (15.04 I believe), when I first start it up it connects just fine to the Wi-Fi network I use. But after using the internet for some time it all of a sudden disconnects and I'm unable to connect again to the router I use. It's says "wifi networks disconnected". But the strange part is when I boot Windows 7 on my computer it's able to stay connected to the Wi-Fi network and access the Internet, it's just the Ubuntu OS I seem to be having some trouble with here.

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/785799/internet-keeps-failing-despite-connected-wifi-on-16-04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may just be an internal error.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install network-manager
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Do that then reboot.

Comment: Well, that did seem to help. But I notice that when I connect a bluetooth headset to it, it disables the wifi. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: @234Nico I know what's causing it, but unfortunately, not how to fix it. This is a problem caused by the motherboard not being able to port both wireless, and bluetooth devices at the same time. I'd recommend asking an entirely new question on it.

Comment: Ok, thank you though for all of the help! Even though you may not know how to fix it, I still am very happy that I know now what's causing the problem.

Comment: I tried this but its not working in Ubuntu 16.06. Instead it uninstalled my network-manage and I was unable to re install it manually by getting the file from downloading the file from other computer.

Comment: @UmarAsghar This answer is over two years old, and is statedly designed around 15.04, and as such may not work with all versions

Comment: When i run this command in Ubuntu 18.04.1 then my Ubuntu setting window not open and i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @ShivaManhar See the answer below this, by NatoBoram It will fix the issue you are having

Comment: @David when i try this code. show error  Package network-manager is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: thank you worked for me

Comment: I wonder how to reinstall network-manager when my network connections wont work at all. Wifi / ethernet / tethered phone / 3G modem - nothing! Same laptop can go over the internet via Wifi without a problem from Windows

Comment: Please do not try this fix. By following this fix basically you are removing the network manager (on line 1 itself). Unless you have network manager, how would you connect to the internet and then reinstall network manager. A workable solution would be use an Ubuntu live usb and chroot into the root partition as outlined here. https://askubuntu.com/a/728388/1087684

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to use [David](https://askubuntu.com/a/653985/620831)'s answer, the Settings shortcut might be missing. To fix that, I used [cshubhamrao](https://askubuntu.com/a/453441/620831)'s answer to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`.

```
sudo apt purge network-manager
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install network-manager
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been searching for this fix for a week now.