# Internet keeps failing despite connected wifi on 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, internet

I saw similar questions, but unlike stated in other questions, My WiFi does not disconnect. Only the connectivity to Internet keeps dropping.

I have tried at different location (different WiFi), the problem is same. 
Any time I just disconnected from Internet (WiFi shows connected to network). After I reboot it works fine. Disconnecting and connecting to WiFi again does not help.

I have other devices (phone and mac) which have no such problem, so I am sure there is nothing wrong with the WiFi router.

EDIT:
As requested here is the command output:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8270]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Added the output to the question as requested.

Comment: You say: "After I reboot it works fine. ".  Does that mean that after rebooting it works for as long as you need it no matter how long that is, or does it mean it works for a while and then the same thing happens again?

Comment: Run `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi disable_11n=1"` and reboot.

Comment: @Stormlord It works fine for a while. 
Pilot6, I will try this now. Thanks.

Comment: @Pilot6 Problem is still happening after doing this. It worked for about 50 mins after reboot. I see a slight pattern now though. The issue occurs mostly if I leave the system idle for a while (not suspended though). I have set my laptop to never sleep.

Comment: I mistyped the command. Please do it again with this `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"` You can also find my nswer with all options. You can try to pick one that helps.

Comment: The problem appears to have been fixed. Yesterday it worked fine for nearly 3 hours. Could you post it as an answer I will mark as accepted. thanks.

Comment: I am sinking with the same issue.  But this solution didn't help.  Can some one save me ?

Answer (score 6):

Just so that we don't have an unsolved question which is actually solved by [this comment by Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785799/on-16-04-internet-keeps-disconnecting/850827#comment1179444_785799)

This command seems to work (it worked for me and the original poster):

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

Comment: I have tried this fix. But still same issue.  After I executed this tee command, nothing has been changed in iwlwifi-opt.conf file.  Please help me.

Comment: I wasn't using my Ubuntu laptop for longer times as I was working on a different machine for almost a year now. Last few weeks I started using my Ubuntu laptop again and the problem is still there but there is no pattern. Some times it works for 3/4 hours without an issue, other times internet gets disconnected almost immediately after booting up. So the problem is not solved for me still.