# Ubuntu 16.04 Keeps disconnecting from internet while still connected to WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, internet

I have very little experience with ubuntu and I have just built a computer and installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am curently using this usb wifi dongle: [https://www.amazon.com/Edimax-EW-7811Un-150Mbps-Raspberry-Supports/dp/B003MTTJOY/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1465959301&sr=8-3&keywords=wifi+usb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY)

The issue is that at random I stop getting connection to the Internet, pages don't load and ubuntu cannot access any servers, not even through the terminal. I basically stop receiving Internet connection even though the wifi still shows as connected. To solve this I have to disconnect from the wifi and re-connect again. This is getting pretty annoying and I was wondering if you guys could help. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post `dmesg` and `lsusb` output

Comment: The dmesg is too long to paste to the web page, what should i do in this case?

Comment: Please plug in your usb wifi and edit your post. Edit your post with `dmesg|tail` and `lsusb`.

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then EDIT your question to include a link to it. Please also delete your "Answer".

Comment: I'm getting the exact same symptoms..

Comment: Use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785799/internet-keeps-failing-despite-connected-wifi-on-16-04) solution. It works for me.