# Why was my wireless disconnecting every 5 minutes with xenial 16.04?

Tags: wireless

I'm running My wireless was disconnecting every couple minutes and I wasn't sure why. I an answer in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785799/on-16-04-internet-keeps-disconnecting) hidden in the comments:

from @Pilot6

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi disable_11n=1"
```

Now my problem seems to have gotten better because my wifi isn't dropping every 5 minutes; however, it's still dropping (in the sense that I have to reset my connect by clicking on the wifi icon in the upper right). So I'd like to know more about what I can do to solve my wifi issues, but I'd also like to know about the process of solving my wifi issues, and specifically @Pilot6's command shown above.

I understand that `<<<` causes `"options iwlwifi disable_11n=1"` to be [passed as input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/command-line-instead-of) to the rest of the command, which in the case of `tee` I'm pretty sure is (like a tee for plumbing) piping output to both a text file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf` and to `stdout` (so I see it on the screen). I can confirm:

```
server@thinkpad:~/Desktop$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

And so in true *nix fashion one line of text placed in the correct config file solved all my problems ;), but what I'd like to know is why? and how the heck did @Pilot6 know to put it there?

I know that `/etc/modeprobe.d` is a [configuration directory for modprobe](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?5+modprobe.conf), and `man modprobe` tells us:

> modprobe - Add and remove modules from the Linux Kernel

which is making more sense why there are all these text files in that directory that go something like `blacklist*.conf`

so taking another look into `iwlwifi-opt.conf`

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

It seems like maybe Pilot6 is trying to say something like: "there is a module in the linux kernel that is currently enabled that is causing problems so let's disable it"

Is this basically correct from a high level?

And then also, how come this worked for me (at least somewhat)? And how did Pilot6 know to try that?

Attached is the output of  from script found in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

thanks for the help :)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 14 Aug 2016 21:24 PDT -0700

Booted last: 14 Aug 2016 00:00 PDT -0700

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21ce]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8195]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b221 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd integrated camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8192ce              57344  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_pci,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192ce
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
wmi                    20480  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s25' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2600000-f2620000 

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::99:136a:8178:e9be/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18726 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17135383 (17.1 MB)  TX bytes:2771222 (2.7 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Comcast"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Comcast' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:58   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       763     1  0 20:13 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8192ce
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-34-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Comcast
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       4e14a31d-a324-4ae7-9c52-c8fe0088bac3
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1,0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4e14a31d-a324-4ae7-9c52-c8fe0088bac3 | Comcast
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   5affbcb4-41d3-4ccd-90af-c854fc397162 | DIRECT-56-HP OfficeJet 3830
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.10/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1471317244
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.10
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::99:136a:8178:e9be/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2001:558:feed::1
IP6.DNS[2]:                             2001:558:feed::2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s25
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.13-3
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s25' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID                         BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
--                           <MAC '' [AC6]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  84      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Comcast                      <MAC 'Comcast' [AC4]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        
--                           <MAC '' [AC2]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        
xfinitywifi                  <MAC 'xfinitywifi' [AC7]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  --         no        
Comcast                      <MAC 'Comcast' [AC1]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       yes     * 
TP-LINK_49E1                 <MAC 'TP-LINK_49E1' [AC16]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
rvac                         <MAC 'rvac' [AN7]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
DIRECT-56-HP OfficeJet 3830  <MAC 'DIRECT-56-HP OfficeJet 3830' [AN8]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
2WIRE665                     <MAC '2WIRE665' [AC14]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
eTours360                    <MAC 'eTours360' [AN10]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
ATTwIBX8I2                   <MAC 'ATTwIBX8I2' [AC15]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
rvac                         <MAC 'rvac' [AC5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
--                           <MAC '
```