# Losing connection to internet while still connected to the network

Tags: wireless, internet

I installed ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and, since the day I did, I've been having internet trouble.  After connecting to any wi-fi network, I will have normal internet access for a little bit.  However, after several minutes (sometimes seconds) I will lose all connection to the internet.  I'll still be connected to the network (I've verified that I still can send and receive ARP packets).  I've scoured forums looking for a solution but nothing works (including [Internet keeps failing despite connected wifi on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785799/internet-keeps-failing-despite-connected-wifi-on-16-04)).  The only relief I've found is to run

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

However, this is a (very) temporary fix.

Comment: If you run `lspci` in a terminal, you'll see a list of PCI devices, one of which should include your wifi adaptor. For example, mine is `03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)`. Can you please post this?

Comment: 01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)

Comment: I am also sinking with the same problem  Can anyone help me.  SOS

Comment: 01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: I'm also suffering from the same problem, except my connection can last for more than a couple of minutes. But still, every so often I have to reconnect to the same network to make it work again.