# persistent ethernet disconnections on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and I am using a wired ethernet connection.

I've been suffering from regular internet drops (the network icon on the top right toolbar dissapears) for 5-10 seconds. The wifi on my laptop continues working throughout the period of connection outage. When the intenet is working, it is running fine at ~100Mb/s.

I have tried following the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/653985/692431), but the problem persists.

```
lscpu

Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           94
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:                        3
CPU MHz:                         800.079
CPU max MHz:                     4000.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        6799.81
Virtualisation:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        1 MiB
L3 cache:                        8 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cach
                                 e flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB condit
                                 ional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx f
                                 xsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rd
                                 tscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts 
                                 rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperf
                                 mperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx s
                                 mx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid s
                                 se4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_t
                                 imer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dno
                                 wprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ss
                                 bd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
                                  ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle a
                                 vx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx s
                                 map clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1
                                  xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify 
                                 hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a2bd
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (Q270)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM] (rev 87)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation Device 0116
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Texas Instruments XIO2001 PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM] (rev 87)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 8c:ec:4b:6b:16:43
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.0.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:128 memory:ee200000-ee21ffff
```

This is a log of when my slack-desktop failed to connect

```
Jul  8 08:44:45 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:45:100] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:46 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:46:101] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:47 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:47:101] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:48 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:48:102] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:49 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:49:103] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:50 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:50:104] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:51 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:51:104] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:52 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:52:106] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:53 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:53:106] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 08:44:54 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 08:44:54:106] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 09:22:08 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:08:792] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:10 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:10:769] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:11 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:11:770] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:12 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:12:771] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:13 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:13:771] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:15 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:15:768] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:16 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:16:769] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:17 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:17:770] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:18 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:18:813] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 09:22:20 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 09:22:20:768] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 10:22:12 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:12:126] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:13 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:13:128] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:14 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:14:128] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:15 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:15:129] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:16 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:16:130] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:17 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:17:131] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:18 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:18:132] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:19 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:19:133] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:20 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:20:134] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:22:21 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:22:21:135] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 10:28:13 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:13:007] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:14 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:14:008] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:15 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:15:009] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:16 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:16:010] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:17 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:17:011] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:18 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:18:012] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:19 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:19:012] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:20 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:20:013] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:21 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:21:014] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:28:22 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:28:22:015] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 10:55:03 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:03:799] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:04 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:04:799] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:05 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:05:800] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:06 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:06:801] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:07 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:07:802] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:08 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:08:803] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:09 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:09:804] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:10 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:10:805] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:11 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:11:806] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 10:55:12 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 10:55:12:807] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 13:17:21 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:21:171] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:22 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:22:172] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:23 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:23:172] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:24 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:24:173] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:25 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:25:174] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:26 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:26:175] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:27 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:27:175] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:28 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:28:177] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:29 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:29:178] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:17:30 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:17:30:179] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 13:43:33 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:33:072] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:34 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:34:073] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:35 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:35:074] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:36 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:36:075] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:37 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:37:076] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:38 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:38:078] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:39 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:39:078] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:40 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:40:079] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:41 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:41:080] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:43:42 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:43:42:081] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 13:51:43 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:43:785] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:45 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:45:768] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:46 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:46:769] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:47 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:47:771] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:48 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:48:771] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:50 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:50:768] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:51 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:51:769] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:52 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:52:770] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:53 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:53:771] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 13:51:55 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 13:51:55:768] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 14:27:09 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:09:781] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:10 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:10:782] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:11 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:11:783] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:12 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:12:784] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:13 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:13:785] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:14 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:14:785] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:15 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:15:786] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:16 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:16:787] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:17 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:17:788] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 14:27:18 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 14:27:18:789] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
Jul  8 17:10:03 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:03:785] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 1 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:05 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:05:768] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 2 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:06 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:06:769] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 3 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:07 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:07:769] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 4 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:08 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:08:770] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 5 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:09 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:09:771] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 6 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:11 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:11:768] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 7 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:12 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:12:769] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 8 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:13 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:13:770] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 9 attempt(s); Retrying in 1000ms.
Jul  8 17:10:14 sam-OptiPlex-7050 slack.desktop[7345]: [07/08/20, 17:10:14:794] info: [NETWORK-CONNECTIVITY] Failed to establish a connection after 10 attempt(s).
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added the times when my slack desktop couldn't find a connection (which should include all the drops since it is open all the time). I guess your second point might be true, but this was a problem since I got a brand new (expensive) cable.

Comment: When slack intermittently drops out, does your web browser still connect? Or is all network connectivity briefly lost?

Comment: All network connection is lost - I was just using slack dropping out as a proxy of when it occurred (since I wasn't sure how to specify exactly when the network dropped)

Comment: Since your wireless keeps running properly, it does not seem to be your Ubuntu networking stack, nor your router software (though the router could probably use a power-cycle, just on general principles). That circles the accusing finger back toward hardware: Ethernet hardware on the laptop, ethernet hardware on the router, and/or the cable. See what  suspects you can eliminate.