# How do I fix my ethernet connection constantly disconnecting on laptop?

Tags: internet, laptop, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with the Plasma 5.24.7 desktop installed on my laptop, which was originally made for Windows. I use an ethernet cable for the internet.  Usually, it works fine, however, every dozen minutes or so the computer considers the cable as disconnected and continuously tries and fails to reconnect. This happens for a while, ranging between half a minute and half an hour, before the cable finally registers as connected and I can use the internet again.  I think this is a software issue, because I have tried using the same cable to connect to another device, and I never have this issue, also, no damage has been done to the physical laptop that I know of.

Someone asked me to put this here:

```
    lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:12aa]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Update: Tried this:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

As instructed here: [wifi and ethernet keep disconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653983/wifi-and-ethernet-keep-disconnecting) , and it did not solve it, but only remove the icon in the system tray for the internet connection.

When I try to access websites on a browser while the issue is occurring, it gives this response:

```
ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the line from `lspci` that identifies the Ethernet device.

Comment: Or more precisely: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Thanks.