# Ubuntu 16.04 Network messed up, no internet connection

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, vpn, cisco

As I was  just trying to install *cisco anyconnect* on *Ubuntu 16.04*, and I probably messed up with the systems network settings. As it didn't work straight forward, I tried to get some help from the forums and performed the steps some people were describing to be able to get cisco anyconnect to run in Ubuntu. After going through the step I ended with a messed up system. Now I cannot connect into the internet at all, no matter if wired or wireless... Network app doesn't even show any connections and throws the following message:

`The system network services are not compatible with this version`

Below is the command line history. Before line 619 everything was fine. After line 744 I have a messed up network system and cannot connect to internet (wired) anymore. Note, that I was/am not using wireless connection for this system... At least not for now.

Could someone please help to roll back to the previous system (bevor applying the commands after line 619) and to install cisco anyconnect in a clean way?

```
619  cd ../anyconnect-4.2.04018/
621  cd vpn/
633  sudo ./vpn_install.sh 
635  ./vpn
636  ./acinstallhelper 
639  sudo rm /var/crash/* 
651  sudo ./vpn_uninstall.sh 
653  cd ..
654  mv Downloads/anyconnect-3.1.08009/ .
655  cd anyconnect-3.1.08009/
657  cd vpn/
659  sudo ./vpn_install.sh 
660  systemctl daemon-reload
662  sudo ./vpn_uninstall.sh
676  cd anyconnect-4.2.04018/
678  cd vpn/
680  sudo ./vpn_install.sh 
681  sudo ./vpn_uninstall.sh 
682  sudo apt-get purge network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
683  sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager-openconnect
684  sudo sed -i s/#deb-src/deb-src/g /etc/apt/sources.list
685  sudo apt-get install libnm-dev
686  wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/NetworkManager-openconnect/1.1/NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93.tar.xz
688  mv NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93.tar.xz ~/
691  tar -xf NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93.tar.xz 
692  cd NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93/
693  ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
694  make
695  sudo apt-get install intltool
696  ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
697  sudo apt-get install gtk
698  ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
700  cd Downloads/
702  sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
707  mv networkmanager-openconnect_1.1.93-1_i386.deb  ../
708  cd ../
709  sudo dpkg -i networkmanager-openconnect_1.1.93-1_i386.deb 
710  cd NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93/
711  ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
712  sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev
713  sudo apt-get -f install
714  sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev
715  ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
716  sudo apt-get install libsecret-common libsecret-1*
717  ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
718  sudo apt-get install openconnect*
719  ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
720  make
721  cd NetworkManager-openconnect-1.1.93/
722  ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/ --enable-more-warnings=yes --disable-static
723  gksu "service network-manager start"
724  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
725  cd /etc
726  cd network/
727  sudo vim interfaces
730  cd
732  sudo dpkg -i networkmanager-openconnect_1.1.93-1_i386.deb 
733  sudo apt-get purge network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
734  sudo apt-get -f install
735  sudo apt-get update
737  sudo dpkg -r networkmanager-openconnect 
739  sudo dpkg -r network-manager-vpnc*
740  sudo dpkg -r network-manager-vpnc-gnome 
741  sudo dpkg -r network-manager-vpnc
743  ifconfig
744  history
```

Comment: Have you tried walking backwards through the command history to repair the issue?

Comment: please run `which NetworkManager` does it return any thing?

Comment: This issue is solved following these instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access.  Also thanks for your comments. I had no network manager at all...

Comment: My advice use a `Virtual Machine` first to test out these kind of things, then if it works then you can install on your linux. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: This is a good advice. I will follow it for the next time, if I try to install system related stuff. Thx!