# Can't find the network connections icon on the menu bar

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

Recently due to my bad my os (windows 10)was gone and all of the data was recovered(May be rebooted) to Ubuntu os (which was given at the time of purchase) through dell recovery. This is done when I tried something unwanted in windows bios settings. Now when I restart my computer it's showing like 
"preparing automatic recovery" and then "diagnosing your pc" and then
 a screen appears with an error unable to diagonise. Two options are shown, Either shutdown or
advanced options.
 When I click advanced options and then clicking on "use a device"  then Ubuntu option appeared. I have been going through this procedure every time I start my pc. Is there any solution to avoid this?
  Another problem is that when I login to Ubuntu, there is no network connection symbol in the menu bar.  I was not able to access the WiFi and even the ethernet cable is not getting recognized. 
 I have tried few things in the terminal such as starting the network manager from terminal which outputs that it is unrecognised. 
Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: For Windows problem, did you try repairing it by Windows installation media?
For Network problem did you try reinstalling network-manager?
Check if this helps : https://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access

Comment: Thankyou vishesh. But when I tried to reinstall it its saying no Internet connection. And I cannot connect to any network. Even ethernet cable is not recognized. Its saying that it is hard blocked.   How can I enable my network manager which was blocked by hard ware. When I type alt + f2   a search bar appears and when I type nm-applet is shows under search , but when clicked its not opening at all.   I don't know what to do now.