# No edit connection option in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network-manager

I have installed ubuntu OS 16.04 on my new system. I am not able to see network interfaces on terminal, only loopback 0 interfaces is what i see.

After few troubleshooting command from youtube/google now i dont see edit connection option. Typing “Sudo apt-get —-purge remove network-manager“ command i dont see edit connection option now. So from my another laptop i downloaded respective network-manager package and but couldn’t install it in my new system

Could someone please help me setting up network interface so that i can connect to internet. I have wifi at home and i have connected my system through LAN cable and wants it to assign ip address automatically.

Please please..any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Reinstall `network-manager`, or `apt-get download` it on a network connected system  copy the `.deb` file to a USB key, move the USB key, and use `dpkg` to install. Read `man apt-get dpkg`.

Comment: "*but couldn’t install it*" does not tell us anything about the problem you encountered. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1267332/edit) to describe the *exact* problem you are encountering. Help us to help you.

Comment: I have downloaded network-manager_1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb, when i opened that and clicked on install button i can see below details like version: 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, license:Open Source, Source:Ubuntunothing happens

Comment: I have downloaded network-manager_1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb & network-manager-gnome_1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb. When i opened that and clicked on install button i can see below details like Version: 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3,                 license:Open Source.     Source:Ubuntu                               Size: 9.8MB.                                                               When i click on OPEN SOURCE it takes me to below website and because i dont have internet access nothing opens.   https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing. Same with gnome network-manager.deb

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access

Comment: I am planning to uninstall ubuntu and install 16.04.7 desktop amd64.iso. This should definitely resolve my problem. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Now i have uninstalled previous version i.e 16.04.6 LTS and installed 16.04.7. Now someone please guide me how to connect it to internet. Ifconfig shows only loopback interface. I could troubleshoot but little scared of running into the problem again. It took lot of time for me to install this OS back.

Comment: I am seeing only 
auto lo iface lo inet loopback

Comment: When i did cd /etc/NetworkManager i can see below files. 1)Conf.d  2)dnsmasq.d  3)NetworkManager.comf 4)VPN  5) dispatcher.d  6)dnsmasq-shared.d  7)system-connections

Comment: Sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf shows managed to false which i changed to true. Also i did sudo service network-manager restart and rebooted the system but nothing changed

Comment: Lspci | grep -i network shows 28.00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a). And for ethernet it shows 26.00.0 Ethernet controller:Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8125 (rev 04).  When i issued sudo lshw -C network i didnt see any drivers keyword in output. In capabilities i have: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list. Does this mean i have drivers missing??? Please help