# WiFi icon not showing ubuntu 20.04 unable to connect to network

Tags: wireless

I'm not seeing the WiFi icon on laptop. I've started facing this issue recently after some update that happened. I'm not able to connect to network as well.

Comment: Appreciate any help/guidance to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the driver may be missing for the wireless card.

You could try checking "Software & Updates" in your menu - then look in the "Additional Drivers" tab.

If nothing is there, then I recommend researching to see where you can get the drivers, starting with:

1. Manufacturer's website - they may provide a Linux driver - or even an Ubuntu-specific driver
2. Figure out what network card you have (eg. from Manufacturer's website) and search for Linux/Ubuntu drivers for that card

Edit: It could also be an issue with Network Manager - you could try [re-installing that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try reinstalling. Weird thing is it automatically connects again after I restart the laptop 2 or 3 times.

Comment: Wow, that is very strange...