# How do I reinstall Network Manager etc as my wired & wifi internet connections don't work?

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Neither my wired & wifi internet connections work after a freeze. On rebooting this led to the BIOS stating that there were some orphaned inodes. I let the BIOS 'fix' these. However, connection to both wired & wifi interfaces don't work. I suspect that Network Manager and/or its dependencies/files are corrupted. How can I 'reinitialise' networking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall network manager without internet access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access)

Comment: @graham Partially answers the question. In the referred to web page, it states that the <chroot location is typically the label of the partition it's installed on. However, on my SSD, according to gparted, sda1 is /boot/efi and sda2 has no label or name. Should I use gparted to give that partition a name or label?

Comment: You seem to be on the dangerous path to a Well-known Error: Applying a "solution" before diagnosing the problem. Reinstslling NetworkManager won't help you, unless you've trashed it.

Comment: @waitinator Possibly on a dangerous path but I have not been able to diagnose the cause. Reinstalling Network Manager is unlikely to make things worse as router connection is only possible by usng my phone as a Hotspot. I have backed up my data. I may have to 'clear' my SSD and reinstall Ubuntu etc etc.

Comment: Using 'sudo smartctl -i -a /dev/sda', it shows for '202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain' the number 1. Does this mean that I should change my SSD ASAP? 
PS I've been having lots of problems connecting to my router and even my Phone as a Hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to everyone trying to help. It turns out that the problem is the computer: a 4 month old Asus mini PN50-1. I suddenly remembered that the same thing had happened last August and that the supplier had given me a replacement after I returned the original.