# Update removed NetworkManager - how to recover?

Tags: networking

I ran an update on my system and something went horribly wrong.  Midway through, it lost connectivity but I let it continue thinking it was just updating something to do with networking.  The update completed, but networking was still out.

I've tried restarting, I've tried a new config in /etc/netplan/config.yaml and then sudo netplan generate and sudo netplan apply, still no luck.

I can use bluetooth, but I haven't found a way to share the connection (on a working system, I can see that it's in the GUI settings -> Network which isn't working on the broken system as it requires NetworkManager)

Any ideas on how to recover from this?

Comment: WiFI? Ethernet LAN? If you use LAN you can manually run `dhclient` on it try to get a DHCP address, and if you use WiFi you can try to use `wpa_supplicant` to login to a WiFI network. If you have a reasonably current Android phone, you can use USB tethering if you don't have LAN but do have WiFi.

Comment: I managed to get wifi going with this sudo iwconfig <device> essid <access_point_name> && sudo dhclient <device> from https://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access and tried apt update and apt upgrade still facing the same problem after a restart

Comment: Trying to install network-manager, looks like I've got broken packages

Comment: So I'm on the pre-release version of 24.04 and I can't seem to figure out what source I need to add to be able to install libnetplan1 on which network-manager is dependant.  I see it here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/noble/amd64/libnetplan1/1.0-1 but I just can't seem to get apt to pick it up.  I'm probably missing something silly.  Anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: Decided to just manually dl and then install with dpkg

Still not sure why I wasn't seeing it in my sources, but it was what I needed to get network-manager installed and get wifi working properly again

Comment: What Ubuntu product/release are you using?  eg. what you describe is a known & tracked (*high* severity) issue on Ubuntu *noble* still in *alpha* and thus off-topic here... however it's off-topic here.  (FYI:  This box (*I'm using now!*) was hit by it too; as was another install.. but you're off-topic here on *development* and unreleased products).

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I know this is off topic now, but @guiverc where did you find that this was a known and tracked issue?  I googled hoping to find reports but nothing turned up (maybe too new and not yet picked up?)

Comment: Did some searching, lots of hits now!

Comment: the migration of code was well known (*issues since late-Jan talked about; https://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/64bit-time which is also of course being implemented in Ubuntu*)... needing to hit prior to beta freeze (for Ubuntu *noble*) thus looking at a calendar should have told any users that the migration had to be *forced* now...Development ML, Development/team posts on Community Hub etc.  inc. discussions on IRC/matrix/etc

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a problem specific to noble and there's now lots of posts about it showing on Google, including this https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2024-March/042954.html

My solution was to manually download the dependency and install with dpkg, others manually reverted the version of network-manager.  There are reports the issue is resolved although I've not yet confirmed myself.

Comment: The issue is resolved.. but it was a *timing* issue... so if impacted it was due to exactly when you performed `sudo apt update` & your machine saw what was available for upgrade..   Other machines done minutes/hours later may have been impacted differently (*thus different fix*); or not at all.  Code has been migrating from *proposed* to *main*, some mandated *removal & additional* rather package upgrade (*thus any hits after removal was done & before addition; would be more impacted*) but these things are only done during the *alpha* stage of development; which *noble* currently is still in.