# Lose drivers after installation

Tags: drivers

recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 in both cases all drivers are going well at the time of installation, but once completed , restarting the computer appears as though I had not walking me the mouse or the graphics card . my specifications are

motherbroad > Asus P5KPL AM
Processor > Dual Core E5300
Ram > 3 GB
I hope you can help me thank you!
PS. Sorry if you do not understand , use google translator

Answer (score 0):

Does your keyboard work?
After reboot try:

1. Go to tty1: `shift+alt+F1` and log in.
2. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ( a little overdone but just to be sure )
3. After everything is completed just reboot your system `sudo reboot now`

It may be that some software needed was not installed and this may correct that. If this doesn't solve the problem go to tty1 again, log in, and type `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` -> again, some dependencies might not be resolved.

**Note 1.**
Only after I wrote this I thought that you may not have an internet connection since you've never log in and connect to a network.
In order for this to work you will need to connect to a network with internet access. So I'll try to describe to you how to connect to an WiFi network but you can check it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/294320/324428) for more info about both WEP and WPA/WPA2. I won't copy and past it here but I'll add a few notes with some output. I've done some research and I couldn't find a way to connect to a WPA/WPA2 network without installing `wpa_supplicant` so I can't really help with that. ( if someone knows *how to* fill free to edit this )

***Connecting to a WEP Network***
First of all, you will need to check the name of your wireless card using `iwconfig`. This will give an output similar to this:

```
$ iwconfig
    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

    lo        no wireless extensions.
```

In this case, the card name is *wlan0* but it can be different in your case so check your output for the one that don't say: `no wireless extensions`.  Also remember that, although not explicit in the link I shared, you will need to run almost all commands with root-level permission so don't forget to append `sudo` to the beginning of every command ( or just log in to root using `sudo -i` ).

Hope it helps somehow.

---

Don't forget to up vote if you found this useful.

Comment: @NachoGalliano , did it work?