# How to log in to an internet provider with with a password and user name through terminal?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, login, lan

I have an account through a wire network internet provider - a person that have an internet LAN and share it with neighbours in exchange with money - every one of us have an account and a password , when we need to access the internet we open the Firefox page and the welcome page of this provider will appear asking us to enter the password and the user name.
after accepting password and user name it will gave you the ability to access internet and the welcome page  will not appear again unless you logout or unplug the network LAN .

The problem is : I need to enter this network by a script through the terminal , because some times I leave home and an analytical program which needs internet is working and the internet for any reason unplugged - a network regular deactivation- I am not there physically to enter the password and the account again.

I need to write a script if the network go off it enter the password and the user account automatically when it came back to life.

Thank you for your concern :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer online [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal)

Open the terminal.

Type `ifconfig wlan0` and press [Enter]. You will not see any output in the terminal, as this command just turns your wireless card on. Most wireless cards are designated `wlan0`. If yours has a different designation, use that instead.

Type `iwconfig wlan0 essid name key password` and press [Enter]. Replace name with the actual network name, and replace `password` with the actual security key for the network. If your wireless network does not require a security key, do not enter key password.

Type `dhclient wlan0` and press [Enter] to obtain an IP address and connect to the WiFi network.

What I see on the terminal are given below.

Comment: Thank you very much but it didn't work it is an Ethernet not  a wireless could you please help me as it's a very urgent  for me