# How do I get wifi to work? HP Pavilion x360

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, hp, realtek-wireless

Have a [HP Pavilion x360 13-s000](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-13-s000-x360-Convertible-PC/7771386/model/8341281/drivers#Z7_3054ICK0KGTE30AQO5O3KA30B3). Can't seem to get the wifi working on either Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04. Did multiple Google searches, but now I'll just ask. The wifi card is a Realtek RTL8723BE [10EC:B723]. Can someone help me get this working?

This is what it said after running `lshw` in terminal

```
*-network DISABLED
            description: Wireless interface
            product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 00
            serial: d8:5d:e2:62:9d:e5
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.19.0-28-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

After running `rfkill unblock all` it still shows wireless is softblocked.

`rfkill list all`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

**UPDATE**
I have followed the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem), however the issue remains unresolved. My wifi has never once worked yet, if that helps at all.

The output of `rfkill list all` is now

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

The Wireless LAN and acer-wireless seemed to have switched positions.

Solution: buy a different laptop......

Comment: "`*-network DISABLED`"? That's a hint. Type `rfkill list all`, then read `man rfkill`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: Even after follow the solution to that link, the wifi still does not work. It has never worked from the start either.

Comment: I have the same computer and the same issue, did you solve it ?

Comment: Hello BlueMagma, unfortunately I still have not solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't run Ubuntu (Fedora) but had the same problem (wifi not switching on) on an HP PAV x360 and also had the same symptoms, namely:

```
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
```

You need to blacklist the acer_wmi module (it never should have been loaded!)

```
[root@localhost ]# lsmod | grep acer
```

Edit (or create if it doesn't exist) /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Add the following lines

```
# Disable acer_wmi as it breaks wifi on this model
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Now unload the module (it will be blacklisted on the next boot so you only need to unload once)

```
[root@localhost ]# modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

Enjoy your working wifi!

Thanks to the smart and kind folk at:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=204162
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet#TOC-Turn-the-kernel-module-acer_wmi-off-or-on

Comment: worked but I also needed to connect via terminal, UI didn't pickup http://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal

Comment: You may wish to state how to create/edit the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file to avoid confusion