# wireless softblocked on my hp pavilion 360...found solutions but need more info

Tags: networking

what does this mean to "Edit (or create if it doesnt exist)"

and then "add the following lines"

I copied the following text from an answer that i think will work but i dont know how to implement it

> You need to blacklist the acer_wmi module (it never should have been
>   loaded!)
>
> ```
> [root@localhost ]# lsmod | grep acer
> ```
>
> Edit (or create if it doesn't exist) /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
>
> Add the following lines
>
> ```
> # Disable acer_wmi as it breaks wifi on this model
> blacklist acer_wmi
> ```
>
> Now unload the module (it will be blacklisted on the next boot so you
>   only need to unload once)
>
> ```
> [root@localhost ]# modprobe -r acer_wmi
> ```

thank you for your help

Comment: It seems that the answer you found lacks some carriage return at crucial points, so the actual instructions and the comments are mixed and thus quite confusing if you see it for the first time. What is meant, is that you (as root) edit the file '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'. If the file does not exist, then you should create it. The line to add to the file is: blacklist acer_wmi

Comment: I really appreciate your time but I dont understand how to create a file.  Would you please show me exactly what I have to type.  I apologize but I am just learning.  I want so badly  to use Linux on my laptop.  The last laptop I had was given to me by a friend and it already had Mint on it.  I love it!  Thanx again

Comment: Please see the answer I will enter right after this comment. Give me a few minutes to complete it...

Comment: I assume you mean one of these questions https://askubuntu.com/questions/678162/how-do-i-get-wifi-to-work-hp-pavilion-x360 https://askubuntu.com/questions/682938/dual-boot-ubuntu-windows-10-on-hp-pavilion-x360 . Also usually for this sort of question please use https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos to get relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mind to show you how to create a file or modify an existing one. The problem is I don't know which editor you have on your system and/or whether you have experience using it. That is why I have entered an alternative solution:

```
$ sudo su
[sudo] password for ....: 
# echo "blacklist acer_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
# exit
exit
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

What this code does is append the quoted string to the blacklist file. If the file does not exist, the system creates it.
The `cat` command lists the content of the file. If the file already existed, you will see other blacklisted modules before the addition you just made.

N.B. Please be aware that I take no responsibility for what editing the blacklist file may result to. You mentioned that you think it will resolve your wireless issue. There is no way for me to confirm that.

PS. You will have to reboot the system for the changes to become active.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have to create or edit the file, either by using a editor or just a command

To use a editor, you can run

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

The `sudo` bit runs the command as root - which is required to gain permission to access protected resources such as system configuration files. The editor in this case in `nano`, a command line editor, which you can type (or paste in, usually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) the `blacklist acer_wmi` line (the line above prefixed by a `#` is just a comment so if you read the file later you know what it is).

Alternatively you can use a command like this

```
sudo bash -c "echo blacklist acer_wmi >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"
```

Which runs in a root shell the echo command to echo the string to the end of the file.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming none of this will work unless I install the Linux first?  My first problem is rebooting after entering the commands.  It doesnt save the changes.  Will they work if I used a Persistant Live usb boot?

Comment: Yeah that would be the issue :) The installer only gives a example environment in which to run stuff. You can install to another USB or similar though it would be slower as it won't be a compact system running out of memory like the installer does. Using `modprobe -r  acer_wmi` should work temporarily but you will have to run it each time you start the USB live installer