# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS no internet connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

Am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the internet was working fine at first now it connects to the WiFi but with no internet connection, this problem only happens on my network.

If I connect my Ubuntu using my mobile as a hotspot using my mobile company data or to any other network it connects normally and the internet works fine. Every other device that is connected to the network is working fine.

Comment: Can you please use some punctuation to make your description easier to understand ?

Comment: There is a similar question which you can take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal

Comment: @AnantGupta I am already connected to the network but with no internet