# Disco Dingo Wireless Network

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

My basic question is that Ubuntu 19.04 does not show a network list the day I sign on. I am sure solving the problem should be simple I just don't have a clue right now.

Additional Drivers recognizes my iMac "airport" wireless card but hangs to install for hours then fails to.

And so I bought this brand new 1200 MBPS wireless USB adapter with the antenna (Inamax 1200) and it came with the CD, so I copied the RTL88x Linux folder onto my partition, and ran the `sudo bash install.sh` command. I did not know how to use update on this package.

The next thing I tried to install `net-tools` by downloading on my other laptop and copying through flashdrive. Used `sudo apt-get update` but still it gave me a warning error and `ifconfig wlan0` did not work.

This is where I am at in my progress: [Connect to WiFi network through Ubuntu terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal)

Comment: Please click [edit] then add to your question exactly what you tried, and exactly what appeared when you tried. Please do not click [Add Comment] as comments get pushed off the screen when new comments arrive.

Comment: By the way, the RTL88x file turned out to be the RealTek LAN driver. I went through the code when it made an error: