# After upgrade goes to wallpaper but no icons or connections

Tags: upgrade, desktop-background, 19.10

After upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10, boots to wallpaper for about 10 seconds no icons of connections, then blank screen. Cannot do anything but can use terminal. Sorry but I'm novice and ask for help with this. 19.04 worked fine so is it possible to return to that version?

Sony Vaio
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with upgrades. The best action would be to boot to the older system.
The first way of doing it while booting hold `SHIFT` button till you see Grub menu. Select older version and press `ENTER`, if you don't see older version select

> Advanced options for Ubuntu

and press `ENTER`, then select older versions.
After booting OS you can try to reinstall the upgrades. If not sure what to do edit **grub.cfg** and add the older version to the top.

If nothing works, connect to WiFi ([description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal)).

Then reinstall latest upgrades and fix Ubuntu ([description here)](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/)

If both does not work, try this help from [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=735693).

If that doesn’t work, backup user files and try clean install of latest Ubuntu. I would not do it, though.

Comment: Booting to older version of Linux did nothing. How do l edit the grub.cfg? How do I return to previous v 19.04? Or how do I install updates for this 19.10 (which is obviously not working)?