# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS stucks on a black screen with a desktop

Tags: grub2, syslinux

I work on a Desktop that has an Ubuntu 20.04 operating system. When booting, the screen is black and I don't have the option to choose my account. I tried doing Ctrl+Alt+F2 and logged in. The problem is that the internet no longer works to do the updates. It worked before[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XemQF.jpg)

Comment: Hello. A few things there is no version 20.4, maybe you mean 20.04 LTS if so please correct the question. Also has it ever worked? What did you do just before this happened if it worked before ?

Comment: If it is truly a network error (which seems unlikely), try running `ifconfig wlan0 up` to turn on your WiFi card. This should solve the error with network. There are other potential solutions on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal

Network errors should not affect the screen.

Comment: Since network errors do not affect the screen, try re-enabling (or restarting) the services. For example, try running `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service` Hopefully it doesn't freeze your computer. If it does, reboot completely. (power button off, power button on)