# Uninstalled Ubuntu desktop and network manager

Tags: 20.04, network-manager

While attempting to fix an issue I was having with my internet connection, I uninstalled network manager. After this I couldn’t reinstall it so I looked on a forum online and it said to uninstall and reinstall ubuntu desktop.
Since I did this I’m unable to reinstall the network manager and can’t download ubuntu desktop since I’ve no internet connection.

Comment: Hello. Any question needs to have the version of Ubuntu you are trying to install. What issue were you having? Why did you uninstall the network manager? What is the link to the site that told you to remove the desktop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to WiFi network through Ubuntu terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal)

Comment: @David hi! The version is 20. The original issue was that I couldn’t connect to the internet. So I uninstalled network manager. Then I feel I may have misinterpreted a forum online which lead me to uninstall Ubuntu desktop. Now I cannot login and cannot reinstall either. Also as far as I’m aware I can’t just erase it and reset it to default settings either. So I’m a little lost

Comment: @david I tried to look for the site but can’t find it, I looked it up on the computer which I can’t get access to now