# "Wired Network Disconnected" even when connected- no ethernet connection possible

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet

I am unable to connect to the internet via Ethernet or WiFi.  Let's fix the Ethernet issue, eh?  I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP Mini 1000.  Previously it had 11.04, and the Ethernet didn't have any issues then.  I am a Linux beginner, and I have been working on this issue for the past several days without any progress.

Here are some outputs:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:feafc000-feafffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:25:b3:48:e7:60
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:42 memory:febfc000-febfffff ioport:ec00(size=256)
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated     Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try going to "software and updates" (from the dash) then go to the tab where there are proprietary drivers; if you find any that are disabled enable them.

Comment: Unfortunately, this screen doesn't show any available proprietary drivers since I do not have a network connection.

Answer (score 29):

Found the solution:

In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, I changed **managed=false** to **managed=true**.

Then run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and voila.

Comment: Tried with fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. I did not specify the Wifi Networks when installing Ubuntu - when installed, found that wifi adapter was showing up in ifconfig,iwconfig, but Wi-networks were still showing as disconnected - my personal wifi was working and connected on other machines. Simply restarting the network-manager as stated above displayed the wifi networks in vicinity. Thanks, ricky!

Comment: Had same issue on Fedora and `sudo service NetworkManager restart` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Mine got fixed from changing from 100mbps lan4 port to 100/1000mbps lan1 which is the fastest one, hope this helps

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @RohithMadhavan How is this not an attempt to answer the question?

Comment: @RohithMadhavan this answer helped me, not fully but gave me some clues. It adds value to resolving this issue. As another answer says "sometimes NetworkManager can be a bit of a diva".. so any clues are helpful. Besides downvoting new users that are trying to be helpful is not encouraging for better contributions from them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes `NetworkManager` can be a bit of a diva, and start messing with things you don't want it to. Try to take the mac address of the physical device you want to connect with `ifconfig wlan0` for your wireless device, or `ifconfig eth0` for an ethernet device. Copy everything after HWaddr. Then edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` You will need to edit it with super user privileges. Add

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:<copied HWaddr>;
```

Then you can connect manually which is talked about here [How do I connect to a WPA wifi network using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line)

Good luck!

Comment: The link you sent me to requires me to install a package... which I can't do as I have no network connection.

Also, I am unable to connect via wifi through terminal any other way as there is no logical name for my wlan card as you can see in  my lshw -C network.

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent 2 hours trying to get my network back using the Network  Manager and the terminal. Guess what fixed it.....turning off the modem, unplugging it, replugging it and switching it back on again. You can see the IP address codes, dns etc reappear in the Network Manager window if you leave this open. I'm thinking this is a "static lock" issue which sometimes happens with my Sky tv box. Hope this helps someone