# Wifi disconnects after laptop is suspended

Tags: wireless, 16.04, suspend

I'm experiencing WiFi disconnects after suspending my laptop or closing the lid. I'm relatively new to Linux, so after I restarted my PC the problem was fixed again. However, it still says that I have disconnected from the internet **whenever** I suspend/close the lid of my laptop. I've noticed that I actually haven't disconnected from the internet and I can still access websites. The menu no longer shows a WiFi logo but shows two arrows in opposite directions and when you click on it the WiFi Networks are grayed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/398986/501519).

Apparently you had to go into `NetworkManager.conf` and edit the file from `managed=false` to `managed=true` and then open up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type in `sudo service network-manager restart`