# How to block access to all SSIDs except for a preferred SSID

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I work in an enterprise environment and I need to block access in Ubuntu 14.04 to any unapproved SSID in a lab setup. The client only wants users in the lab to be able to access one specific SSID and hide or block access to any other SSID (Other Corporate Wifi Networks, Personal Hotspots, etc..).

I am currently doing this with the Windows devices in the same lab, but I haven't found a way to do this within Ubuntu devices. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to get rid of the network manager entirely, and only [configure](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line) one AP to autoconnect.

Answer (score 1):

With network-manager, you can enforce a specific access point BSSID via the connection editor <kbd>Edit...</kbd> then select the <kbd>Wifi</kbd> tab and enter the <kbd>BSSID:</kbd>. Obviously this solution requires that your users don't have sufficient privileges to subsequently modify network-manager wireless settings.

[image: nm-connection-editor wifi tab]