# Wireless not working on 16.04 : Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, 16.04, acer

I have Ubuntu 14.10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire 5110. Wireless connection in 14.10 works fine. In 16.04 no connection. With the same settings. Thanks for any help.

Here are the results of running the script wireless-info:

http://pokyrek.cz/wl/wireless-info-ubuntu-14.10.txt

http://pokyrek.cz/wl/wireless-info-ubuntu-16.04.txt

Comment: @SteveRoome: I think you meant to say that Pavel should [edit] his *question*.

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it

Answer (score 0):

From the results of the two scripts it looks like wireless is working fine and you have found another bug in GNOME Network Manager. Please report it. I have written a detailed answer on how to proceed here. [16-04-lts-all-wifi-connectivity-lost-when-changing-wifi-networks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770563/16-04-lts-all-wifi-connectivity-lo)