# Wifi configuration after Ubuntu Server installation

Tags: server, wireless, lubuntu, configuration

I want to install Lubuntu on my Raspi 4 and followed the instructions: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi, steps 1-4.

At the end I can however not continue to do the lubuntu-desktop installation because wifi is not yet configured and I don't have a wired internet (am always using my mobile's wifi). Likewise I can't install any other package but have to work with the configuration that comes with the server distro.

How can I tell Ubuntu Server which wifi connection details to use?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This might be helpful, https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: In the command line interface run the command

```
cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Step 2: At  the end of the file, type this lines

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
    network={
         ssid="Your network name/SSID"
         psk="Your WPA/WPA2 security key"
         key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    }
```

Example: If the SSID is `rocket` and password is `12345678`
you would add

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
    network={
         ssid="rocket"
         psk="12345678"
         key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply!

In /etc I don't have a file "wpa_supplicant.conf" but a directory "wpa_supplicant" containing the files "action_wpa.sh", "functions.sh" and "ifupdown.sh".

Should I create a new file (inside the similarily-named directory?) or modify the existing ones?

Comment: Does someone have an idea?