# How can I connect wifi in ubuntu 18.04 LTS which I recently updated from 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, wireless

I have recently updated the os from version 16.04 to 18.04 LTS. But I can not connect the pc to mobile Hotspot. The wifi is turned on but in the visible networks section no available network is shown. How can I resolve this, please help.

Answer (score 1):

## Using `nmcli` utility(recommended):

We will use the command-line version of Network Manager, `nmcli`.

Scan for available WiFi networks:

```
nmcli d wifi list
```

where **`d`** stands for **d**evices.

Connect to your access point, for example, `my_wifi`:

```
nmcli d wifi connect my_wifi password <password>
```

where `<password>` is the password for the connection.

## Using `ifconfig`:

Check the wireless network device of your card. It usually starts with **w** like `wlan0`, but if you're unsure you can just run `iwconfig`. It will report **"no wireless extensions"** for non-wireless devices and will display some data for any wireless devices.

Now bring up your wireless card as a root user:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Enter your access point name and password using `iwconfig`:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid <my_wifi> key s:<password>
```

where  is the name of your hotspot name and  is its password.

This method works for **WEP** encrypted connections. For **WPA/WPA2** encryptions see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/138472/52726).

Comment: I ran the nmcli d wifi list command. It's showing this "IN-USE SSID MODE CHAN RATE SIGNAL BARS SECURITY".  I'm a noob.. Can't really understand what's going on!

Comment: These are the title headings indicating the info about the wireless networks available. The name of your hotspot must be under SSID column.

Comment: There aren't showing any network available..

Comment: Try using `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` to shut down and again `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` to restart your wifi. Then try again using `nmcli`. Here **wlan0** can be different in your device, use `iwconfig` to check.

Answer (score 0):

First let's test, that your connection is working by doing the following from the terminal

> > ping -c4 8.8.8.8

If that succeeded, you're pinging Google's nameserver's and your connection is fine. You're probably having a misconfigured resolv.conf file which includes the nameserver ip address (nameservers will translate names ie. google.com to ip-addresses).

If you're able to ping, we need to fix your misconfigured resolv.conf file

> > sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
> >
> > sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

Restart networking or reboot

> > sudo service networking restart

Comment: Still visible networks aren't showing in wifi section..

Comment: Hey  I just ran those commands and then the internet just stopped working.. Although wifi is connected.. How do I revert this to previous state?!