How to restore network manager from tty
How to restore network manager from the TTY remember some point internet is disconnected from PC light DM is deleted. I am stuck in this TTY Ubuntu version is 22.04

maybe over wpa_cli https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line

What have you done to your system? How did you get to this condition? This is an XY problem.
