# How can I display the list of available Wi-Fi networks?

Tags: wireless, networking, xubuntu, network-manager

My Ubuntu laptop's Wi-Fi works fine on various Wi-Fi networks. But the list of available networks accessed from the toolbar icon of [nm-applet](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/nm-applet.1.html) no longer appears. I just see the known networks. The list of hidden networks also doesn't show any new networks.

`sudo iwlist scan` likewise only shows known networks.

How do I get a list of all available networks so I can connect to one?

I am using Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Does terminal command `nmcli dev wifi list` give anything additional to what's shown by the GUI applet?

Comment: Also worth noting that `sudo iwlist scan` shows more available networks than `iwlist scan` (without `sudo`) - so this question by itself is helpful. But perhaps it should be renamed to "How can I display the list of *hidden* WiFi networks"?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Use the `nmcli dev wifi` command. It shows transfer rate, signal strength, and security (e.g. [WPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access)) as well:

[image: screenshot after running "nmcli device wifi list]

For more, see [`nmcli`'s manual](https://man.archlinux.org/man/nmcli.1.en) and [this](https://man.archlinux.org/man/nmcli-examples.7.en) for usage examples of `nmcli`.

Comment: Here is the pertaining mnemonic: **n**_etwork_ **m**_anager_ **c**_ommand_ **l**_ine_ **i**_nterface_ **dev**_ice_ **wifi**

Comment: For me this only found the WiFi network I was connected to rather than all available.

Comment: It requires `sudo` to display the entire list.

Comment: The BSSID (MAC of remote access point) and other details are not shown by default, but you can show them with the `-f` option, e.g. `nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,DEVICE dev wifi`. Use `-f ALL` to see available fields.

Comment: @icc97 - if you only see your current network, run `nmcli dev wifi rescan`, wait a bit, and then try `nmcli dev wifi` again.

Comment: For more details `nmcli d --help`

Comment: `nmcli` is part of `network-manager` so if not installed yet then run `sudo apt install network-manager`

Answer (score 79):

To scan all networks try using the command `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep SSID`.

You can find more info in the AU answer [How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/16588/362944)

Comment: wlan0 should be replaced  with real value from ifconfig of from /sys/class/net  subfolder name, as stated in answer from @gujarat santana

Comment: This works better than nmcli for me because it breaks down and shows non-latin characters, where nmcli just shows a "?"

Comment: @EkriirkE well, for a more detailed breakdown on wifi networks in nmcli command you could use `-f ALL` option, e.g. `nmcli -f ALL dev wifi`. Although I admit, it's still not as detailed as `iw`'s information.

Comment: @Hi-Angel  Not sure the relevance?  We just want SSIDs not even more technical info

Comment: @EkriirkE sorry, I probably misread your comment. You stated that it worked better for you since "it breaks down", and I thought you meant "breaking down" as in "showing detailed information". With that said, I am not sure who are "we" ☺ I definitely wanted the technical details on the networks, and the question or the answer don't seem to limit the question to just SSIDs.

Answer (score 21):

In Ubuntu 16.04:

1. Go to `/sys/class/net` you can see list of directories here.
2. Find the wireless interface. It has **wireless directories**, for example in my case it's `wlp10`. You can check it using `ls wlp10`. **If the directory's name different, use that directory's name**.
3. `sudo iwlist wlp1s0 scan | grep ESSID`

From here you can list all available Wi-Fi access points.

Source [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Scan_for_Wireless_Network).

Comment: Note this does not work with broadcom wireless cards.

Comment: @JaredSmith do the other solutions work with broadcom wifi cards?

Comment: @DanEsparza they should

Answer (score 8):

Further to what has been already answered here, I've merged a few of them and added a little flavor of my own.

As for the `nmcli` answer, sure, do that if you want to install more software. But if you're looking for Access Points, maybe you don't have an internet connection yet and are unable to connect to install said software. With all that said, here's my solution:

```
for i in $(ls /sys/class/net/ | egrep -v ^lo$); do sudo iw dev $i scan | grep SSID | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$2)) }'; done 2>/dev/null | sort -u
```

Breaking it down:

```
for i in $(ls /sys/class/net/ | egrep -v ^lo$);
```

Lets have a look at all the contents of the location /sys/class/net. This will list all the network devices, but we're not really interested in the loopback interface. so we'll ignore that one

```
do sudo iw dev $i scan | grep SSID | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$2)) }';done
```

For each of the network interfaces we found above, lets do the scan to list all the SSIDs (and only the SSIDs)

```
2>/dev/null
```

And ignore all the errors (like searching for SSIDs with ethernet interfaces).

```
| sort -u
```

And finally, If you have multiple wi-fi adapters on the system, only list each SSID once.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but if you want to just check for just wireless devices (and leave lo and ethernet devices alone), you can do the following:
`for i in /sys/class/net/*; do [ -d "$i/wireless" ] && sudo iw dev $(basename $i) scan | grep SSID | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$2)) }'; done | sort -u`