# TL-WN823N USB + Ubuntu Mate + Raspberry PI

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on a Raspberry Pi 2. I installed a TL-WN823N USB wireless USB device, however, unlike what I read on the internet about this device and ubuntu, it is in no way detected.

`dmesg` tells me its placed at device number 5, that its idVendor 2357 and idProduct 0109. Also; its Realtek.

`lsusb` lists the device as 2357:0109 - and thats all (no text / titles).

`lsmod` shows nothing wireless related

`iw-config` shows only lo - no wireless connection

It seems the device, in no way, is detected for what it is and no drivers are used. The drivers I can find help for, is x86 based, not arm. Any help is really appreciated.

Edit: this is raspberry pi specific. the possible duplicate points to precompiled binaries for x86. Does not necessarily answer this ubuntu+raspberry pi question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TP-LINK TL-WN823N Unable to connect to network](http://askubuntu.com/questions/813443/tp-link-tl-wn823n-unable-to-connect-to-network)

Comment: @Pilot6 will your driver build for ARM?

Comment: MrEngman @ raspberrypi.org has drivers compiled for ARM.

Comment: @chili555 It is a source package. If it is ARM, it probably some configs need to be changed.

Comment: The driver has settings for ARM, CONFIG_PLATFORM should be changed. I did not test if something else needs to be done. But it is not hard to port the patch if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone else, after sitting with this problem several hours and FINALLY deciding to ask a question, I find the answer a few minutes later.. go figure.

Its here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=148389&p=1028428

follow the debian process, it works just fine for ubuntu mate. after this, just go into networks, add a network - pick the new device that its found. This doesn't fix lsusb, but everything else shows the correct stuff :-)

Have fun.