# Wifi is not activated, but by restarting network-manager

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ssd

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. LTS on my computer. When I reboot, the wifi device is said to not be ready and no connection is established. After typing "sudo service network-manager restart", it connects without any problem. 
The question was asked in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843335/wifi-interface-down-on-boot-need-to-restart-network-manager). 
I tried to add the driver of the device (r8712u) to "/etc/modules" as it is advised there, but to no avail. The thread talks about the fact that a boot from an SSD-Drive causes this problem since it "boots too fast". This actually seems to be the culprit since I don't have this problem if I run Ubuntu on my HDD-Drive.
Hence, the question is how to work around this problem, e.g. by switching to another kernel?

Edit: Now, I kind of found a solution by removing the network-manager altogether and using wicd with startup applications, although I think that this solution is somewhat unsatisfying since I have not understood why it works with a HDD and not with a SSD. In that sense, the question is still up as I would be very interested as to the reasons because there might be other issues coming up that stem from the same root of the problem, but I guess it is not "fatal" for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by removing the network-manager with

```
     sudo apt-get remove network-manager
```

after having installed wicd, of course. Then, I added wicd to the startup applications and it works now. Only on the first recovery from suspension do I have to refresh and reconnect the desired network, but it works.