# How do I get a TP-Link TL-WN823N V3 wireless adapter working?

Tags: drivers, wireless, tp-link

I have Ubuntu 19.04 (kernel: 5.0.0-13-generic; gcc version: 8.3.0) installed on an old pc that has a broken Wi-Fi card. So I replaced it with an external TP-Link
wireless USB adapter. But I cannot follow the instructions:

https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201812/20181207/Installation%20Guide%20for%20Linux.pdf

I already downloaded these files and sent to the PC from another one, as it has no internet connection:

https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/tl-wn823n/#Driver

If I have to compile (I don't even know what it means) the driver, I don't know what it means "go to the driver directory and run the following commands".

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/813443/tp-link-tl-wn823n-unable-to-connect-to-network

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 30):

If you have internet access by any other means (wired or through USB tethering), you can installed the RTL8192EU drivers for your TP-LINK TL-WN823N wireless adapter from [Mange's GitHub repo](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver). Here are the steps as described on the GitHub page:

**Building and installing using DKMS**

(1) Install DKMS and other required tools:

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

(2) Clone this repository and change your directory to cloned path.

```
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
```

(3) Add the driver to DKMS. This will copy the source to a system directory so that it can used to rebuild the module on kernel upgrades.

```
sudo dkms add .
```

(4) Build and install the driver.

```
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

(5) Distributions based on Debian & Ubuntu have RTL8XXXU driver present & running in kernelspace. To use our RTL8192EU driver, we need to blacklist RTL8XXXU.

```
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
```

(6) Force RTL8192EU Driver to be active from boot.

```
echo -e "8192eu\n\nloop" | sudo tee /etc/modules
```

(7) Newer versions of Ubuntu has weird plugging/replugging issue (Check #94). This includes weird idling issues, To fix this:

```
echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf
```

(8) Update changes to Grub & initramfs

```
sudo update-grub; sudo update-initramfs -u
```

(9) Reboot system to load new changes from newly generated initramfs.

```
systemctl reboot -i
```

(10) After the reboot, you can check that your kernel has loaded the right module:

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

You should see the line `driver=8192eu`

Comment: thank you very much in linux mint 19.3 tricia it worked perfectly ... perfect end

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for linux mint 20.1 Cinnamon... it says driver=r8169 and the wifi adapter does not show up as connected...

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I usually hesitate to install drivers from github for security reasons. I fear there might be a malicious code or sth (is that possible?) But since mange's repo is mentioned here I think it's trusted

Comment: @mido I'm glad it worked out for you, and yes, drivers from his repo are used by many.

Comment: I was struggling with a TP-Link TL-WN823N in Ubuntu 20.04. Worked nicely!

Comment: Thank you very much, this driver saved me from a very slow wifi connection... I cannot understand why it was good with an old adapter, and very slow (specially in upload) with a new and more powerful adapter.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to @Jags' comment, there is a simpler script to automate all his/her steps under the following repo.

I have validated myself on Ubuntu 20.04 and it works wonderfully.

- Clone this repo: `git clone https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux`
- Under the repo, run `./install_wifi.sh`

Done! :)

Comment: Can confirm this worked perfectly on ubuntu 20.04.1. You can also download a zip of the repo here https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux and copy it to your machine without internet with a flash drive.

Comment: Yes, working on Ubuntu 21.04, much easier than the driver installation instructions, which require editing the makefile.

Comment: Worked for me on 20.04.

Comment: worked on 22.04.1