# Wifi, ethernet and USB Tethering no longer working after installing graphics card driver

Tags: wireless, nvidia, tethering, tp-link

this weird thing happened:

After installing Ubuntu 20.10 AMD64 in my PC, I couldn't connect to wifi even though I had the wifi icon and connections list showing up. The USB tethering worked however. Then I installed the drivers for the wifi adapter (TP LINK TL WN823N) according to this tutorial: [How do I get a TP-Link TL-WN823N V3 wireless adapter working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211157/how-do-i-get-a-tp-link-tl-wn823n-v3-wireless-adapter-working)

Then, as my display wasn't working properly, I installed the suggested video drivers (for my GeForce GT1030) using the autoinstall and rebooted.

Now the graphics are ok - but the wifi option disappeared, the ethernet wire connection is not working and so do the USB tethering. Using the lsusb command I can see that the system detects the wifi adapter - but I have no wifi options...

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reinstall wireless drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6, I've tried to do this, but the terminal said it was already installed... The work around was to reboot from an older kernel, then updating the whole system at once. Now both graphics and internet are ok.

Comment: It looks like you found a solution. Consider converting your comment to a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this with:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-$(uname -r) linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```