# wpa_supplicant does not connect with "ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument" error!

Tags: networking, 12.04, wireless, wpa-supplicant, text-mode

Ubuntu Server 12.04 is installed on my desktop system (in text-mode, no X-Window is available) and I have no wired Ethernet connected, just wireless network is available. I use TP-Link TL-WN723N USB wireless adapter to connect to wireless network.

At first, tried to use `iwconfig` to connect, but found that it could not be used to connect to a WPA2 secured network! At fisrt, `iwconfig` shows:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

and `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning` shows:

```
wlan0   Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down
```

after running `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`, `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning` shows:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MYESSID12345"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000789abcdef
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000123456789ABCEDF0123456789
                    IE: Unknown: 0123456789ABCDEF0123
                    IE: Unknown: 012345
                    IE: Unknown: ABCEDF
                    IE: Unknown: 0123456789AB
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

I installed `wpasupplicant` to connect to wireless network secured with WPA2. But there are some problems using this package:

I tried following instructions in [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal)

```
wpa_passphrase 'MYESSID12345' 'MYPASSWORD$1234567' > CONFIG_FILE
```

after above command, I edited CONFIG_FILE (`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`) so it contains:

```
network={
    ssid="MYESSID12345"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="MYPASSWORD$1234567"
    proto=RSN WPA
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    #psk=1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcedf1234567890abcdef
}
```

Next i run `wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext -dd`. The result is following errors on `stderr`:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

and `stdout` is:

```
Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' driver 'wext' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
Line: 1 - start of a new network block
ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67               MYESSID12345
scan_ssid=1 (0x1)
key_mgmt: 0x2
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=18): [REMOVED]
proto: 0x3
pairwise: 0x18
group: 0x18
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='MYESSID12345'
WEXT: cfg80211-based driver detected
SIOCGIWRANGE: WE(compiled)=22 WE(source)=21 enc_capa=0xf
  capabilities: key_mgmt 0xf enc 0xf flags 0x0
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=1, operstate=5
Own MAC address: mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_countermeasures
RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
Setting scan request: 0 sec 100000 usec
WPS: UUID based on MAC address - hexdump(len=16): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
Added interface wlan0
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b06 len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=8
State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING
Scan SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67               MYESSID12345    
Starting AP scan for specific SSID(s)
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 5 seconds
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8
Received 656 bytes of scan results (2 BSSes)
BSS: Start scan result update 1
BSS: Add new id 0 BSSID OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO SSID 'MYESSID12345'
BSS: Add new id 1 BSSID 11:11:11:11:11:11 SSID 'OTHER1'
New scan results available
Selecting BSS from priority group 0
Try to find WPA-enabled AP
0: OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO ssid='MYESSID12345' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11
   selected based on RSN IE
   selected WPA AP OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO ssid='MYESSID12345'
Request association: reassociate: 0  selected: OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO  bssid: 00:00:00:00:00:00  pending: 00:00:00:00:00:00  wpa_state: SCANNING
Trying to associate with OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO (SSID='MYESSID12345' freq=2412 MHz)
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
Cancelling scan request
WPA: clearing own WPA/RSN IE
Automatic auth_alg selection: 0x1
RSN: PMKSA cache search - network_ctx=(nil) try_opportunistic=1
RSN: Search for BSSID OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
RSN: Consider OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO for OKC
RSN: No PMKSA cache entry found
RSN: using IEEE 802.11i/D9.0
WPA: Selected cipher suites: group 8 pairwise 8 key_mgmt 2 proto 2
WPA: clearing AP WPA IE
WPA: set AP RSN IE - hexdump(len=22): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab
WPA: using GTK TKIP
WPA: using PTK TKIP
WPA: using KEY_MGMT WPA-PSK
WPA: not using MGMT group cipher
WPA: Set own WPA IE default - hexdump(len=22): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
State: SCANNING -> ASSOCIATING
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstatioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
e 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
wpa_driver_wext_associate
wpa_driver_wext_set_drop_unencrypted
wpa_driver_wext_set_psk
Association request to the driver failed
Setting authentication timeout: 10 sec 0 usec
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP fail=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portControl=Auto
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b06 len=8
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=20
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c08 len=24
AssocResp IE wireless event - hexdump(len=16): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b15 len=20
Wireless event: new AP: OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
Association info event
resp_ies - hexdump(len=16): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
State: ASSOCIATING -> ASSOCIATED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
Associated to a new BSS: BSSID=OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
Associated with OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
WPA: Association event - clear replay counter
RSN: PMKSA cache search - network_ctx=0x9c8e950 try_opportunistic=0
RSN: Search for BSSID OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
RSN: No PMKSA cache entry found
WPA: Clear old PTK
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=1
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state CONNECTING
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
Setting authentication timeout: 10 sec 0 usec
Cancelling scan request
RX EAPOL from OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
RX EAPOL - hexdump(len=99): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Setting authentication timeout: 10 sec 0 usec
IEEE 802.1X RX: version=1 type=3 length=95
  EAPOL-Key type=2
  key_info 0x89 (ver=1 keyidx=0 rsvd=0 Pairwise Ack)
  key_length=32 key_data_length=0
  replay_counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
  key_nonce - hexdump(len=32): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
  key_iv - hexdump(len=16): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  key_rsc - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  key_id (reserved) - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  key_mic - hexdump(len=16): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
WPA: RX EAPOL-Key - hexdump(len=99): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
State: ASSOCIATED -> 4WAY_HANDSHAKE
WPA: RX message 1 of 4-Way Handshake from OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO (ver=1)
RSN: msg 1/4 key data - hexdump(len=0):
WPA: Renewed SNonce - hexdump(len=32): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
WPA: PTK derivation - A1=mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm A2=OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
WPA: PMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: PTK - hexdump(len=64): [REMOVED]
WPA: WPA IE for msg 2/4 - hexdump(len=22): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab
WPA: Sending EAPOL-Key 2/4
WPA: TX EAPOL-Key - hexdump(len=121): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
RX EAPOL from OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
RX EAPOL - hexdump(len=161): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
IEEE 802.1X RX: version=1 type=3 length=157
  EAPOL-Key type=2
  key_info 0x13c9 (ver=1 keyidx=0 rsvd=0 Pairwise Install Ack MIC Secure Encr)
  key_length=32 key_data_length=62
  replay_counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
  key_nonce - hexdump(len=32): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
  key_iv - hexdump(len=16): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
  key_rsc - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  key_id (reserved) - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  key_mic - hexdump(len=16): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
WPA: RX EAPOL-Key - hexdump(len=161): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
RSN: encrypted key data - hexdump(len=62): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab
WPA: decrypted EAPOL-Key key data - hexdump(len=62): [REMOVED]
State: 4WAY_HANDSHAKE -> 4WAY_HANDSHAKE
WPA: RX message 3 of 4-Way Handshake from OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO (ver=1)
WPA: IE KeyData - hexdump(len=62): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab
WPA: RSN IE in EAPOL-Key - hexdump(len=22): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab
WPA: GTK in EAPOL-Key - hexdump(len=40): [REMOVED]
WPA: Sending EAPOL-Key 4/4
WPA: TX EAPOL-Key - hexdump(len=99): 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
WPA: Installing PTK to the driver.
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=2 key_idx=0 set_tx=1 seq_len=6 key_len=32
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=1
State: 4WAY_HANDSHAKE -> GROUP_HANDSHAKE
RSN: received GTK in pairwise handshake - hexdump(len=34): [REMOVED]
WPA: Group Key - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: Installing GTK to the driver (keyidx=1 tx=0 len=32).
WPA: RSC - hexdump(len=6): 00 00 00 00 00 00
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=2 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=6 key_len=32
WPA: Key negotiation completed with OO:OO:OO:O:OO:OO [PTK=TKIP GTK=TKIP]
Cancelling authentication timeout
State: GROUP_HANDSHAKE -> COMPLETED
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->1 (UP)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=6
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=1
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=1
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state AUTHENTICATING
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state SUCCESS
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state AUTHENTICATED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Authorized
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
EAPOL authentication completed successfully
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
EAPOL: startWhen --> 0
EAPOL: disable timer tick
CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING - signal 2 received
Removing interface wlan0
wpa_driver_wext_deauthenticate
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
State: COMPLETED -> DISCONNECTED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 1->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
wpa_driver_wext_set_countermeasures
No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
BSS: Remove id 0 BSSID OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO SSID 'MYESSID12345'
BSS: Add new id 1 BSSID 11:11:11:11:11:11 SSID 'OTHER1'
Cancelling scan request
Cancelling authentication timeout
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=0, operstate=6
```

after the last command, `wlan0` goes DOWN and I have to make it up using `sudo iwconfig wlan0 up` command again.
Also I tried removing `network-manager` package based on a comment saying this may solve the problem, but no success.

Also tried to edit `wpa_supplicant.conf1` file as follows:

## TRY #1 for `wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
network={
    ssid="MYESSID12345"
    #psk="MYPASSWORD$1234567"
    psk=1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcedf1234567890abcdef
}
```

## TRY #2 for `wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
network={
    ssid="MYESSID12345"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    #psk="MYPASSWORD$1234567"
    proto=RSN WPA
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    psk=1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcedf1234567890abcdef
}
```

Comment: Could you try to connect with nl80211 driver? Use 'wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D nl80211' command. Also, did you install firmware for this driver?

Comment: I tried removing `#psk="MYPASSWORD$1234567"` from my `wpa_supplicant.conf` file (TRY#1) and the problem has solved (`wpa_supplicant` connected to my AP and after running `sudo dhclient wlan0` I could access Internet). After that I recreated the CONFIG_FILE using `wpa_passphrase 'MYESSID12345' 'MYPASSWORD$1234567' > CONFIG_FILE` command and it creates a new CONFIG_FILE same as **TRY #1** and the problem did not occurred again!

Answer (score 13):

First of all, I think you'll have better luck if your router is set to use WPA2-AES and not TKIP.

Second, I believe you are taking the long, complicated route when the short, easy route would work perfectly well. First, I suggest you back up your current wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
sudo mv /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf  /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.bak
```

Next, I suggest you edit /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-essid MYESSID12345
wpa-psk MYPASSWORD$1234567
```

Of course, substitute your details here. Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping results, you are connected.

Comment: The problem with this approach though, is that in bypassing wpa_supplicant your PC won't reconnect to the wifi if connection is lost.

Comment: thanks so much... i wasted one day but when i applied your answer it worked...

Comment: Can I copy your  address netmask and gateway values?  If not what do I put in there?

Comment: @lightsout I think this a complex question and I recommend that you start your own. I’ll be happy to help.

Comment: Or you can reboot. I think the 'down' part can safely be ignored. Did the 'up' part seen to connect?

Comment: @chili555 I want to try this script on a different computer but the wlan0 on that computer is called wlp2s0 instead, will this still work?

Comment: @lightsout A new question, please.

Comment: I spent an entire day fiddling with wpa_supplicant. Then I tried this and it worked. Linux in a nutshell ...

Comment: I'm still struggling. Using a static or dhcp address, it seems to refuse to connect. The SSID I'm using has spaces in it, however both using quotes around it and not using quotes does not work. Am I supposed to use the value generated by wpa_passphrase for the wpa-psk value? Either way i.e using that, or using plain text does not work (the password has no spaces)

Comment: @DaveNottage I suggest that you start your own new question and show your file. The wpa-psk should be in clear text. It should, of course, be disguised in your question.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks for the very speedy reply, however it turns out I needed to install a package for the firmware (an alternative manual install apparently doesn't cut it). All good now, using your answer here!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this today as well. I pulled out a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file that has worked for me in the past on my Raspberry Pi devices and used it here. Once I tried with this file, my `wpa_supplicant` was consistently connecting.

I took some time today to try and disable some of the `network=` sections to try and narrow down which one section was applicable for my wireless network, but I gave up after a while. Taking out and putting back individual sections seemed to be narrowing things down, but then I don't know why it still wasn't connecting, so I gave up and put the whole thing back in there and got myself a DHCP IP address from my router.

Here was the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file I used:

```
network={
    ssid="MYESSID12345"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="MYPASSWORD$1234567"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    priority=999
}

network={
    ssid="MYESSID12345"
    psk="MYPASSWORD$1234567"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    priority=99
}

network={
    ssid="MYESSID12345"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=NONE
    priority=2
}

network={
    ssid="MYESSID12345"
    psk="MYPASSWORD$1234567"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    priority=-1
}
```

With this, I ran:

```
$ sudo -i
# cd /etc/wpa_supplicant
# wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i wlp1s0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
...
wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to ... completed [id=0 id_str=]
```

I still got the same errors in stdout, but things still looked better and more info in `/var/log/syslog` than before.

After this in a separate console:

```
# dhclient -v -r wlp1s0
# dhclient -v wlp1s0
```

I got my IP address and so I was able to proceed:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
```