# Script bash that connect into wifi

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, scripts

i've created a script bash that suppose to connect on wifi dynamically.If is WPA, WEP, without password, with static ip or DHCP.

There is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Open script..."
#NO PASSWORD
if [ $3 ==  0 ]
then
    echo "Without Password..."
    iw dev wlan0 connect $1
fi

if [ $3 == "WEP" ]
then
    echo "Auth mode WEP..."
    iw wlan0 connect $1 key s:$2
fi

if [ $3 == "WPA" ] || [ $3 == "WPA2" ]
then
    echo "Auth mode WPA"
    echo "ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    update_config=1
    network={
            ssid=\"$1\"
            psk=\"$2\"
    }" | sudo tee --append /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf > 
 /dev/null

    echo "Finished to write on wpa supplicant..."
    sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext
fi

if [ $4 == "DHCP" ]
then
    echo "dhcp mode on..."
    dhclient wlan0
else 
    echo "dhcp mode off..."
    #ifconfig wlan0 $5 netmask $6 up
    #route add default gw $7
    #echo "nameserver $8">/etc/resolv.conf
 fi

 #SET DNS 2
 if [ $9 != 0 ]
 then
    echo "dn2 configuration..."
    #echo "nameserver $8">/etc/resolv.conf
 fi

 #RESTART UP
 echo "restarting process..."
 #ifconfig eth0 down
 #/etc/init.d/networking restart
 #pm2 stop 0
 #pm2 delete 0
 #pm2 start ecosystem.json
```

That's all, some commands are commented because is not finished yet. My problem is the script didn't working. I give the permissions on the wpa_supplicant.conf, but still is do not want to work.

My errors are:

```
Finish to write on wpa_supplicant...
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
dhcp mode on...
restarting process...
stderr RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

All variables works fine when i run script, but somehow still can't connect into wifi. I tried to use `nl80211` instead and it gives me this error:

```
Failed to create interface 
p2p-dev-wlan0: -16 (Device or resource busy) nl80211: Failed to create 
a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlan0 P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device 
interface
```

More verbose errors:

```
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0x1b9f4a0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=040b
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=040c
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=040d
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=090a
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 09 0a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=090b
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 09 0b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=090c
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 09 0c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=090d
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 09 0d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=0409506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=6): 04 09 50 6f 9a 09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=7f506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=5): 7f 50 6f 9a 09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=0801
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 08 01
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) 
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=040e
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation 
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0e
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION)              
nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=06
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation     
already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=1): 06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION)     nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=0a07
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
 nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 0a 07
 nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION)         nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=0a11
 nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
 nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 0a 11
 nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION)     nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=1101
 nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation     already in progress)
 nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 11 01
 nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION)     nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=1102
 nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
 nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 11 02
 nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x1b9f4a0 match=0505
 nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
 nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 05 05
 nl80211: Failed to register Action frame processing - ignore for now
 netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=1 (userspace-control), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
 nl80211: driver param='(null)'
 Add interface wlan0 to a new radio phy0
 nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
 nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
 nl80211: 2457-2482 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
 nl80211: 2474-2494 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no OFDM) (no IR)
 nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
 nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
 nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz 20 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
 nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
 nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz 0 mBm
 nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
 wlan0: Own MAC address: b8:27:eb:d0:13:64
 wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
 wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
 wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
 wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
 wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
 wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
 wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
 nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
 TDLS: TDLS operation supported by driver
 TDLS: Driver uses internal link setup
 TDLS: Driver does not support TDLS channel switching
 wlan0: WPS: UUID based on MAC address: 7630b69b-9582-57c5-9979-4b06864bafb4
 ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
 ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
 EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
 EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
 nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
 EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
 EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
 EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
 Using existing control interface directory.
 ctrl_interface_group=108 (from group name 'netdev')
 wlan0: Added interface wlan0
 wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
 nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
 netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
 nl80211: Create interface iftype 10 (P2P_DEVICE)
 Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlan0: -16 (Device or resource busy)
 nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlan0
 P2P: Failed to create P2P Device interface
 P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
 Daemonize..
 dhcp mode on...
 restarting process...
 stderr RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: same error here: https://askubuntu.com/q/652864/507051

Comment: I don't think is same, i can't put down in the file static values

Comment: Maybe try `-D nl80211` instead of `-Dwext`? Coming from here: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-993126.html?sid=e8094ae54a602c348d63bff98c0f828b Playing around with drivers would be my first step. You could also increase the verbosity of `wpa_supplicant` by adding the `-dd` flag and see whether the error messages get more helpful. Btw, does `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext` run from a terminal work?

Comment: I added more verbose errors