# Mistake by un-installing file manager – blank screen

Tags: lubuntu, screen, filemanager, pcmanfm

I have un-installed PcManfm, default file manager from Lubuntu as I was too annoyed by it  and wanted to install Dolphin. To avoid any conflicts I did this before installing Dolphin and stupidly I logged out from the system after un-installing . Now I have only a blank screen...

Is it possible to install PcManfm  back again from a Life Stick. If so how to do it?

Or from Lubuntus rescue mode?  I don't know How to establish an internet connection via Terminal.

Comment: What about launching terminal `ctrl+alt+t`or `ctrl+alt+F1` and `sudo apt-get install pcmanfm`

Comment: I have tried this , but nothing at all is visible. The screen remains black.

Comment: what distro are you using? Ubuntu? Lubuntu? etc. more info you give, the easier it is to help

Comment: On a side note, have you considered installing SpaceFM? it's built by the same people as PcmanFM what has a considerable more amount of features and is still supported.

Comment: I am using Lubuntu 14.04. Have never heard of SpaceFM but the prob was not about features but  PcManfm showed me again and again hidden files and is cutting the time of files under right edge of the screen.

Comment: If the configuring an internet connection from terminal is the main problem, try a wired LAN connection. Usually you do not even need to configure it. Can you 100% confirm that `CTRL+ALT+Fx` with x=1 to 6 does not give you a tty login option?

Comment: I just tried `ctrl+alt+F1` > the terminal starts and I have tried `sudo apt-get install pcmanfm` the system started to execute but couldn’t obviously finished as there is no Internet connection. I don’t know how to get the connection from Terminal. Unfortunately I cant get wired LAN connection . And what is a  tty login?

Comment: @Asklep tty login is the terminal login you have at e.g. `CTRL+ALT+F1`, so this is OK an working. Now you just need to access your WLAN from terminal. Did you try it like [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal)? Try the simple version by user @user82110 first!

Comment: PcManfm is installed now; I wonder how it worked (the files must have been still on the PC). I used tt7 after  `ctrl+alt+F1` and I can login in my sytsem , but the screen is still black. But A click with the right mouse button shows me the context menu of OpenBox. I can  start the terminal emulator and start some applications, PcManfm too via it except network-manager. So, I have no desktop, no task-bar visible, no network manger. I have used lxsession before.