# Trying to find if internet connection is 2.4 or 5ghz, in order to purchase proper tv streaming stick

Tags: internet, streaming

I'm currently in the market for a Tv streaming stick, and I planned on purchasing the chromecast... but I just read that it only runs on 2.4 ghz, and some of the others will run on either 2.4 or 5. I'd still like to get the chromecast, but I have to find out if it will work before I purchase!!
I've already tried 2 methods, to no avail. I installed wifi radar, and there is a decent amount of information shown, but nowhere do I see whether it's running on 2.4 or 5 Ghz (maybe I'm missing something,or it's not plainly stated as ghz?). I also ran the iwlist, I got a message reading: 
"wlan0 Interface doesn't support scanning."
I want to buy the streaming stick in 3 or 4 days, somebody help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask*Ubuntu*! Can you please clarify how your question is related to *Ubuntu*? So far it's not obvious and per our policy only questions about *Ubuntu* are on topic here.

Answer (score 11):

The available wireless frequency will be determined by your router or, if you had configured your computer to provide a hot-spot by the capabilies of your inbuilt wireless card.

I am not aware of any card or router that will only be able to provide a 5 GHz signal - they all can do 2,4 GHz as well, mostly simultaneously or even in parallel so we can use both bands to increase bandwidth.

Informations including frequency about the wireless you are currently connected to will be displayed by this terminal command:

```
iwconfig
```

Also see
- [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)
- [How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal)