# How to connect to internet when system graphics is not working and I can use only terminal

Tags: networking, graphics, 16.04, live-usb, gnome-terminal

How can I run commands on my system in terminal that require internet connection? I am using a live usb. In my system graphics is not working. And I am unable to connect to internet using terminal.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you're asking. Are you having network problems, and trying to fix them from the live usb?

Answer (score 1):

Use wired connection. Connect ethernet cable to your computer's ethernet port. Now you will be automatically connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Wired connection is the best method as no further configurations are required. However, should the wired connection is not available, here are [another Ask Ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal) on connecting to wireless network.