# iwconfig - connect to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I am trying to connect to wifi using terminal without any result.

My ESSID is "HOME", this is what I wrote into the terminal:

```
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 essid "HOME" key s:MYPASSWORDHERE
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) : SET failed on device wlp2s0; Invalid argument."
```

So I tried to connect to an open wifi (my smartphone hotspot) using :

```
sudo iwconfig wlps0 essid "My ASUS"
```

(my android hotspot has no password) without any result or any sort of output...

PS: The same things work very well using GUI, I can connect to HOME (inserting password) and to "My ASUS" without password, as it should be.

Comment: "without any result or any sort of output..." I believe the next step is to ask the access point for an IP address: `sudo dhclient wlp2s0`

Comment: nothing is happening..I wrote that but the console is "stuck" and I have to cancel using ctrl+c..

Comment: AFAIK `iwconfig` still only supports WEP (which I **hope** you are **not** using) - see [How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/16588/178692) for a comprehensive answer

Comment: no ahah I am using WPA2, I am going to see your link, thank you very much!