# Intel Compute Stick network manager not found

Tags: network-manager

I bought an Intel Compute Stick with Ubuntu yesterday. Came home excited and tried it on my TV and the WiFi was working. This afternoon I took it to my office and tried it but it doesn't connect to any WiFi at all (I can see the available networks, press "connect" but nothing happens). Came home and tried it on the same TV and network as last night, but cannot connect now!

The WiFi icon is missing on top as well. Anyone had the same experience? What's the solution? The stick is useless without internet.

Comment: You can launch the network manager applet, aka the wifi icon, with the `nm-applet` command. For serious troubleshooting, you need to post [more info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

Comment: didn't work. it seemed the network-manager-gnome is missing. and i tried [ sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome ] but it says it's not there. i also tried [ sudo apt-get download network-manager-gnome ] but doesn't download.

Comment: Well, apt-get wouldn't work without an internet connection. You can check if the network manager is installed with `dpkg -l | grep network-manager`. If it is missing, are you trying to say that you don't know why or how?

Comment: Ok will try at home tonight. But let's say it is missing because I accidentally deleted it, then how do I fix it? It's a compute stick, so it has no LAN connection for alternative internet connection, and no startup disk to reinstall. Am I screwed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'screwed'. The worst thing that can happen is a reinstall, but before that, you can try the [command way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal).

Comment: So if I do a reinstall, everything will be restored to normal? Network-Manager-Gnome will be available again? So how do I do a reinstall?

Comment: Not exactly. Nothing will be restored. Everything will be wiped and new versions installed. All Ubuntu releases (except server) have the network manager preinstalled. You can start bby visiting here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

Comment: restored and got the wifi working again! thanks. but now sound not working after LTS stack failed to upgrade. dang! what luck.

Comment: Did you update the UEFI firmware (get it from the downloadcenter.intel.com site)?  The sold version may be much older than the current one (FC0035.bio). You can use the micro sd card to get new packages when you don't have wireless working.